# What are the differences between a HashMap and a Hashtable in Java?

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, hashtable

What are the differences between a [`HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HashMap.html) and a [`Hashtable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Hashtable.html) in Java?

Which is more efficient for non-threaded applications?

Comment: HashTable is obsolete in Java 1.7 and it is recommended to use ConcurrentMap implementation

Comment: @MissFiona No, [`ConcurrentMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap.html) is *not* necessary here, as the Question says “non-threaded applications” meaning threading/concurrency is not an issue.

Comment: @BasilBourque, Yes, but I believe what MissFiona meant by that was something akin to _"`HashTable` has traditionally been only chosen because of its partial threading protection.  But that's been obviated by `ConcurrentHashMap`, so it's generally regarded as retired.  It's generally recommended to choose between `HashMap` or `ConcurrentHashMap`."_  And I believe that to be a sensible comment, if it's what she meant.

Comment: According to https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.1602.00984 Hashtable is more efficient than HashMap in terms of both energy consumption and execution time.

Comment: @aventurin I wonder if that is still the case now biased locking is disabled since Java 15.

Answer (score 4233, accepted):

There are several differences between [`HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HashMap.html) and [`Hashtable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Hashtable.html) in Java:

1. `Hashtable` is [synchronized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085709/what-does-synchronized-mean), whereas `HashMap` is not. This makes `HashMap` better for non-threaded applications, as unsynchronized Objects typically perform better than synchronized ones.
2. `Hashtable` does not allow `null` keys or values.  `HashMap` allows one `null` key and any number of `null` values.
3. One of HashMap's subclasses is [`LinkedHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html), so in the event that you'd want predictable iteration order (which is insertion order by default), you could easily swap out the `HashMap` for a `LinkedHashMap`.  This wouldn't be as easy if you were using `Hashtable`.

Since synchronization is not an issue for you, I'd recommend `HashMap`. If synchronization becomes an issue, you may also look at [`ConcurrentHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html).

Comment: If you want to make a HashMap thread-safe, use `Collections.synchronizedMap()`.

Comment: I would also comment that the naive approach to thread-safety in `Hashtable` ("synchronizing every method should take care of any concurrency problems!") makes it very much *worse* for threaded applications. You're better off externally synchronizing a `HashMap` (and thinking about the consequences), or using a `ConcurrentMap` implementation (and exploiting its extended API for concurrency). Bottom line: the only reason to use `Hashtable` is when a legacy API (from ca. 1996) requires it.

Comment: HashMap gives flexibility to programmer to write threadSafe code when they actually use it. It happened rarely that I needed a thread safe collection like ConcurrentHashMap or HashTable. What I needed is certain set of functions or certain statements in a synchronized block to be threadsafe.

Comment: Hashtable is obsolete and we are using HashMap for non thread safe environment.

If you need thread safety then you can use Collections.synchronizedMap()  or use ConcurrentHashMap which is more efficient that hashtable.

Comment: It's obsolete but not deprecated and I'm wondering why this is. I'm guessing removing this class (and Vector for the same reasons) would break too much existing code and annotating with @Deprecated would imply an intention to remove the code, which apparently is not there.

Comment: You can also use ConcurrentSkipListMap (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListMap.html). It is thread-safe collection similar to ConcurrentHashMap and this map is sorted according to the natural ordering of its keys, or by a Comparator provided at map creation time.

Comment: HashTable use single intrinsic lock which result in very poor performance in even in low contention. While Threadsfe counterpart of HashMap i.e. ConcurrentHashMap use lock spliting which is user configurable has multitime better performance even in high contention.

Comment: The Collections.synchronizedMap() requires a lock on the entire object for read/write operations, while ConcurrentHashMap allows concurrent modifications by acquiring locks on separate segments.

Answer (score 798):

Note, that a lot of the answers state that Hashtable is synchronized.  **In practice this buys you very little.**  The synchronization is on the accessor/mutator methods will stop two threads adding or removing from the map concurrently, but in the real world, you will often need additional synchronization.

A very common idiom is to "check then put" — i.e. look for an entry in the `Map`, and add it if it does not already exist. This is not in any way an atomic operation whether you use `Hashtable` or `HashMap`.

An equivalently synchronised `HashMap` can be obtained by:

```
Collections.synchronizedMap(myMap);
```

But to correctly implement this logic you need **additional synchronisation** of the form:

```
synchronized(myMap) {
    if (!myMap.containsKey("tomato"))
        myMap.put("tomato", "red");
}
```

Even iterating over a `Hashtable`'s entries (or a `HashMap` obtained by `Collections.synchronizedMap`) is not thread-safe unless you also guard the `Map` against being modified through additional synchronization.

Implementations of the [`ConcurrentMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap.html) interface (for example [`ConcurrentHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html)) solve some of this by including **thread safe check-then-act semantics** such as:

```
ConcurrentMap.putIfAbsent(key, value);
```

Comment: Also note that if a HashMap is modified, iterators pointing to it are rendered invalid.

Comment: So is there any difference between synchronized(myMap) {...} and ConcurrentHashMap in terms of thread safe?

Comment: Having been in the middle of a JVM development crew for a number of years I can state that Hashtable's internal synchronization is at least useful for properly pointing the finger at the customer's code when he writes dodgy concurrent code.  We received several complaints of failures inside HashMap (and hence "obviously" a JDK/JVM bug), when the cause was concurrent modification.

Comment: The implementation of Collections.synchronizedMap includes a synchronized putIfAbsent, so you don't need to use containsKey/put yourself.

Answer (score 431):

`Hashtable` is considered legacy code. There's nothing about `Hashtable` that can't be done using `HashMap` or derivations of `HashMap`, so for new code, I don't see any justification for going back to `Hashtable`.

Comment: From Hashtable javadoc (emphasis added): "As of the Java 2 platform v1.2, this class was retrofitted to implement the Map interface, **making it a member of the Java Collections Framework**."  However, you are right that it is legacy code. All the benefits of synchronization can be obtained more efficiently with Collections.synchronizedMap(HashMap). (Similar to Vector being a legacy version of Collections.synchronizedList(ArrayList).)

Comment: @aberrant80: unfortunately you have no choice between the two and have to use Hashtable when programming for J2ME...

Comment: Agree that "Hashtable is considered legacy code". You should use ConcurentHashMap instead if you need concurrency.

Answer (score 232):

This question is often asked in interviews to check whether the candidate understands the correct usage of collection classes and is aware of alternative solutions available.

1. The `HashMap` class is roughly equivalent to `Hashtable`, except that it is non synchronized and permits nulls. (`HashMap` allows null values as key and value whereas `Hashtable` doesn't allow `null`s).
2. `HashMap` does not guarantee that the order of the map will remain constant over time.
3. `HashMap` is non synchronized whereas `Hashtable` is synchronized.
4. Iterator in the `HashMap` is fail-safe while the enumerator for the `Hashtable` is not and throw `ConcurrentModificationException` if any other Thread modifies the map structurally by adding or removing any element except `Iterator`'s own `remove()`  method. But this is not a guaranteed behavior and will be done by JVM on best effort.

Note on Some Important Terms:

1. Synchronized means only one thread can modify a hash table at one point in time. Basically, it means that any thread before performing an update on a `Hashtable` will have to acquire a lock on the object while others will wait for the lock to be released.
2. Fail-safe is relevant within the context of iterators. If an iterator has been created on a collection object and some other thread tries to modify the collection object "structurally", a concurrent modification exception will be thrown. It is possible for other threads though to invoke the `set` method since it doesn't modify the collection "structurally". However, if prior to calling `set`, the collection has been modified structurally, `IllegalArgumentException` will be thrown.
3. Structurally modification means deleting or inserting element which could effectively change the structure of the map.

`HashMap` can be synchronized by

`Map m = Collections.synchronizeMap(hashMap);`

Map provides Collection views instead of direct support for iteration via Enumeration objects. Collection views greatly enhance the expressiveness of the interface, as discussed later in this section. Map allows you to iterate over keys, values, or key-value pairs; `Hashtable` does not provide the third option. Map provides a safe way to remove entries in the midst of iteration; `Hashtable` did not. Finally, Map fixes a minor deficiency in the `Hashtable` interface. `Hashtable` has a method called contains, which returns true if the `Hashtable` contains a given value. Given its name, you'd expect this method to return true if the `Hashtable` contained a given key because the key is the primary access mechanism for a `Hashtable`. The Map interface eliminates this source of confusion by renaming the method `containsValue`. Also, this improves the interface's consistency — `containsValue` parallels `containsKey`.

> [The Map Interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html)

Comment: 1) HashMap's iterators are NOT fail-safe.  They are fail-fast.  There is a huge difference in meaning between those two terms.  2) There is no `set` operation on a `HashMap`.  3) The `put(...)` operation won't throw `IllegalArgumentException` if there was a previous change.  4) The fail-fast behaviour of `HashMap` *also* occurs if you change a mapping.  5)  The fail-fast behaviour *is* guaranteed.  (What is not guaranteed is the behaviour of a `HashTable` if you make a concurrent modification.  The actual behaviour is ... unpredictable.)

Comment: 6) `Hashtable` does not guarantee that the order of map elements will be stable over time either.  (You are perhaps confusing `Hashtable` with `LinkedHashMap`.)

Comment: Anyone else really worried that students these days are getting the errant idea that getting "synchronized versions" of the collections somehow means that you don't have to externally synchronize compound operations?  My favorite example of this being `thing.set(thing.get() + 1);` which more often than not catches newbies by surprise as completely unprotected, especially if the `get()` and `set()` are synchronized methods.  Many of them are expecting magic.

Comment: Re 4: ConcurrentModificationException is not about threads. It's about keeping an iterator around and modifying the original collection which may happen in the same thread.

Answer (score 156):

`HashMap`: An implementation of the `Map` interface that uses hash codes to index an array.
`Hashtable`: Hi, 1998 called. They want their collections API back.

Seriously though, you're better off staying away from `Hashtable` altogether. For single-threaded apps, you don't need the extra overhead of synchronisation. For highly concurrent apps, the paranoid synchronisation might lead to starvation, deadlocks, or unnecessary garbage collection pauses. Like Tim Howland pointed out, you might use `ConcurrentHashMap` instead.

Comment: This actually makes sense. ConcurrentHashMaps gives you freedom of synchronization and debugging is lot more easier.

Answer (score 151):

Keep in mind that `HashTable` was legacy class before Java Collections Framework (JCF) was introduced and was later retrofitted to implement the `Map` interface. So was `Vector` and `Stack`.

**Therefore, always stay away from them in new code since there always better alternative in the JCF** as others had pointed out.

Here is the [Java collection cheat sheet](http://pierrchen.blogspot.com/2014/03/java-collections-framework-cheat-sheet.html) that you will find useful. Notice the gray block contains the legacy class HashTable,Vector and Stack.

[image]

Answer (score 118):

There are many good answers already posted. I'm adding few new points and summarizing it.

`HashMap` and `Hashtable` both are used to store *data in key and value form*. Both are using hashing technique to store unique keys.
But there are many differences between HashMap and Hashtable classes that are given below.

**HashMap**

1. `HashMap` is non synchronized. It is not-thread safe and can't be shared between many threads without proper synchronization code.
2. `HashMap` allows one null key and multiple null values.
3. `HashMap` is a new class introduced in JDK 1.2.
4. `HashMap` is fast.
5. We can make the `HashMap` as synchronized by calling this code
   `Map m = Collections.synchronizedMap(HashMap);`
6. `HashMap` is traversed by Iterator.
7. Iterator in `HashMap` is fail-fast.
8. `HashMap` inherits AbstractMap class.

**Hashtable**

1. `Hashtable` is synchronized. It is thread-safe and can be shared with many threads.
2. `Hashtable` doesn't allow null key or value.
3. `Hashtable` is a legacy class.
4. `Hashtable` is slow.
5. `Hashtable` is internally synchronized and can't be unsynchronized.
6. `Hashtable` is traversed by Enumerator and Iterator.
7. Enumerator in `Hashtable` is not fail-fast.
8. `Hashtable` inherits Dictionary class.

Further reading [What is difference between HashMap and Hashtable in Java?](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2010/10/difference-between-hashmap-and.html)

[image]

Comment: Why do you say ~"**Hashtable is a legacy class**"?  Where is the supporting documentation for that.

Comment: Maintaining HashMap is costly than TreeMap. Because HashMap creates unnecessary extra buckets.

Comment: A LinkedHashMap has a doubly-linked list of entries, not of buckets. Buckets are accessible via array indices and need not be linked.

Comment: A 2016 study by Pereira et al. has found that Hashtable is faster than HashMap for most methods, most notably for containsKey, get, put, and remove (arXiv:1602.00984). So your claims "HashMap is fast" and "Hastable is slow" are most likely false.

Comment: I think the expressions "can/can't be shared between many threads" can be misleading to beginners. "can't be shared" does not mean literally can not be shared. Maybe it'd be better to say "should not be shared". But I'm not a native English speaker, so... :)

Answer (score 80):

Take a look at this chart. It provides comparisons between different data structures along with `HashMap` and `Hashtable`. The comparison is precise, clear and easy to understand.

[Java Collection Matrix](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=0Aq3e8BiuZY2wdFpHSlV0QzVmV1lUNHJidGd2b0Zrb3c&single=true&gid=0&output=pdf)

Answer (score 76):

In addition to what izb said, `HashMap` allows null values, whereas the `Hashtable` does not.

Also note that `Hashtable` extends the `Dictionary` class, which as the [Javadocs](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Dictionary.html) state, is obsolete and has been replaced by the `Map` interface.

Answer (score 59):

`Hashtable` is similar to the `HashMap` and has a similar interface. It is recommended that you use `HashMap`, unless you require support for legacy applications or you need synchronisation, as the `Hashtables` methods are synchronised. So in your case as you are not multi-threading, `HashMaps` are your best bet.

Answer (score 54):

`Hashtable` is synchronized, whereas `HashMap` isn't. That makes `Hashtable` slower than `Hashmap`.

For single thread applications, use `HashMap` since they are otherwise the same in terms of functionality.

Answer (score 43):

Another key difference between `Hashtable` and `HashMap` is that the *Iterator* in the HashMap is  fail-fast  while the *enumerator* for the Hashtable is not and throw *ConcurrentModificationException* if any other Thread modifies the map structurally  by adding or removing any element except Iterator's own remove()  method. But this is not a guaranteed behavior and will be done by JVM on best effort.

My source: http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2010/10/difference-between-hashmap-and.html

Answer (score 42):

Beside all the other important aspects already mentioned here, Collections API (e.g. Map interface) is being modified all the time to conform to the "latest and greatest" additions to Java spec.

For example, compare Java 5 Map iterating:

```
for (Elem elem : map.keys()) {
  elem.doSth();
}
```

versus the old Hashtable approach:

```
for (Enumeration en = htable.keys(); en.hasMoreElements(); ) {
  Elem elem = (Elem) en.nextElement();
  elem.doSth();
}
```

In Java 1.8 we are also promised to be able to construct and access HashMaps like in good old scripting languages:

```
Map<String,Integer> map = { "orange" : 12, "apples" : 15 };
map["apples"];
```

**Update:** No, they won't land in 1.8... :(

[Are Project Coin's collection enhancements going to be in JDK8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13692213/are-project-coins-collection-enhancements-going-to-be-in-jdk8)

Comment: The "new way" also works for Hashtable (as it also implements the map interface).

Comment: To be precise `Hashtable` implements neither `Map` nor `Iterable` (which is required for "new" foreach syntax). However, `Hashtable.keySet()` returns `Set` which indeed allows for that syntax.

Comment: **Update**: Well, it **does** implement `Map` in fact... glad to got corrected after so many years in ignorance

Answer (score 35):

- [HashTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html) is synchronized, if you are using it in a single thread you can use [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html), which is an unsynchronized version. Unsynchronized objects are often a little more performant. By the way if multiple threads access a HashMap concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies the map structurally, it must be synchronized externally. 
  Youn can wrap a unsynchronized map in a synchronized one using :

  ```
  Map m = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap(...));
  ```
- HashTable can only contain non-null object as a key or as a value. HashMap can contain one null key and null values.
- The iterators returned by Map are fail-fast, if the map is structurally modified at any time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the iterator's own remove method, the iterator will throw a `ConcurrentModificationException`. Thus, in the face of concurrent modification, the iterator fails quickly and cleanly, rather than risking arbitrary, non-deterministic behavior at an undetermined time in the future. **Whereas** the Enumerations returned by Hashtable's keys and elements methods are not fail-fast.
- HashTable and HashMap are member of the [Java Collections Framework](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/collections/index.html) (since Java 2 platform v1.2, HashTable was retrofitted to implement the Map interface).
- HashTable is considered legacy code, the documentation advise to use [ConcurrentHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) in place of Hashtable if a thread-safe highly-concurrent implementation is desired.
- HashMap doesn't guarantee the order in which elements are returned. For HashTable I guess it's the same but I'm not entirely sure, I don't find ressource that clearly state that.

Answer (score 34):

Based on the info [here](http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=430247), I'd recommend going with HashMap.  I think the biggest advantage is that Java will prevent you from modifying it while you are iterating over it, unless you do it through the iterator.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it will throw a ConncurrentModificationException before the underlying collection is modified, though I could be wrong.

Comment: It will *attempt* to detect concurrent modification and throw an exception.  But if you're doing anything with threads, it can't make any promises.  Absolutely anything can happen, including [breakage](http://lightbody.net/blog/2005/07/hashmapget_can_cause_an_infini.html).

Answer (score 34):

`HashMap` and `Hashtable` have significant algorithmic differences as well. No one has mentioned this before so that's why I am bringing it up. `HashMap` will construct a hash table with power of two size, increase it dynamically such that you have at most about eight elements (collisions) in any bucket and will stir the elements very well for general element types. However, the `Hashtable` implementation provides better and finer control over the hashing if you know what you are doing, namely you can fix the table size using e.g. the closest prime number to your values domain size and this will result in better performance than HashMap i.e. less collisions for some cases.

Separate from the obvious differences discussed extensively in this question, I see the Hashtable as a "manual drive" car where you have better control over the hashing and the HashMap as the "automatic drive" counterpart that will generally perform well.

Answer (score 33):

*A [`Collection`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/intro/index.html) — sometimes called a container — is simply an object that groups multiple elements into a single unit. `Collections` are used to store, retrieve, manipulate, and communicate aggregate data. A collections framework <sup>[W](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_collections_framework)</sup> is a unified architecture for representing and manipulating collections.*

The `HashMap` <sup>[*`JDK1.2`*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html)</sup> and Hashtable <sup>[*`JDK1.0`*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)</sup>, both are used to represent a group of objects that are represented in `<Key, Value>` pair. Each `<Key, Value>` pair is called `Entry` object. The collection of Entries is referred by the object of `HashMap` and `Hashtable`. Keys in a collection must be unique or distinctive. [as they are used to retrieve a mapped value a particular key. values in a collection can be duplicated.]

---

**«** **Superclass, Legacy and Collection Framework member**

*Hashtable is a legacy class introduced in `JDK1.0`, which is a subclass of Dictionary class. From `JDK1.2` Hashtable is re-engineered to implement the [Map interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html) to make a member of collection framework. HashMap is a member of Java Collection Framework right from the beginning of its introduction in `JDK1.2`. HashMap is the subclass of the AbstractMap class.*

```java
public class Hashtable<K,V> extends Dictionary<K,V> implements Map<K,V>, Cloneable, Serializable { ... }

public class HashMap<K,V> extends AbstractMap<K,V> implements Map<K,V>, Cloneable, Serializable { ... }
```

**«** **Initial capacity and Load factor**

*The capacity is the number of buckets in the Hashtable, and the initial capacity is simply the capacity at the time the Hashtable is created. Note that the Hashtable is open: in the case of a [hash collision](http://www.algolist.net/Data_structures/Hash_table/Chaining), a single bucket stores multiple entries, which must be searched sequentially. The load factor is a measure of how full the Hashtable is allowed to get before its capacity is automatically increased.*

*HashMap constructs an empty Hashtable with the default initial capacity **(16)** and the default load factor (0.75). Where as Hashtable constructs empty Hashtable with a default initial capacity **(11)** and load factor/fill ratio (0.75).*

[image: Hash Map & Hashtable]

**«** **Structural modification in case of hash collision**

*`HashMap`, `Hashtable` in case of hash collisions they store the map entries in linked lists. **From Java8 for `HashMap`** if hash bucket grows beyond a certain threshold, that bucket will switch from [`linked list of entries to a balanced tree`](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/180). which improve worst-case performance from O(n) to O(log n). While converting the list to binary tree, hashcode is used as a branching variable. If there are two different hashcodes in the same bucket, one is considered bigger and goes to the right of the tree and other one to the left. But when both the hashcodes are equal, `HashMap` assumes that the keys are comparable, and compares the key to determine the direction so that some order can be maintained. It is a good practice to make the keys of `HashMap` [comparable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31244596/5081877). On adding entries if bucket size reaches `TREEIFY_THRESHOLD = 8` convert linked list of entries to a balanced tree, on removing entries less than `TREEIFY_THRESHOLD`  and at most `UNTREEIFY_THRESHOLD = 6` will reconvert  balanced tree to linked list of entries. <sup>[Java 8 SRC](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java#l244), [stackpost](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43911638/5081877)</sup>*

**«** **Collection-view iteration, Fail-Fast and Fail-Safe**

```java
    +--------------------+-----------+-------------+
    |                    | Iterator  | Enumeration |
    +--------------------+-----------+-------------+
    | Hashtable          | fail-fast |    safe     |
    +--------------------+-----------+-------------+
    | HashMap            | fail-fast | fail-fast   |
    +--------------------+-----------+-------------+
    | ConcurrentHashMap  |   safe    |   safe      |
    +--------------------+-----------+-------------+
```

[`Iterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) is a fail-fast in nature. i.e it throws ConcurrentModificationException if a collection is modified while iterating other than it’s own remove() method. Where as [`Enumeration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Enumeration.html) is fail-safe in nature. It doesn’t throw any exceptions if a collection is modified while iterating.

According to Java API Docs, Iterator is always preferred over the Enumeration.

<sub>**NOTE:** The functionality of Enumeration interface is duplicated by the Iterator interface. In addition, Iterator adds an optional remove operation, and has shorter method names. New implementations should consider using Iterator in preference to Enumeration.</sub>

In [Java 5 introduced ConcurrentMap Interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/collections/changes5.html): `ConcurrentHashMap` - a highly concurrent, high-performance `ConcurrentMap` implementation backed by a hash table. This implementation never blocks when performing retrievals and allows the client to select the concurrency level for updates. It is intended as a drop-in replacement for `Hashtable`: in addition to implementing `ConcurrentMap`, it supports all of the "legacy" methods peculiar to `Hashtable`.

- Each `HashMapEntry`s value is [volatile](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47695757/5081877) thereby ensuring fine grain consistency for contended modifications and subsequent reads; each read reflects the most recently completed update
- Iterators and Enumerations are Fail Safe - reflecting the state at some point since the creation of iterator/enumeration; this allows for simultaneous reads and modifications at the cost of reduced consistency. They do not throw ConcurrentModificationException. However, iterators are designed to be used by only one thread at a time.
- ***Like `Hashtable` but unlike `HashMap`, this class does not allow null to be used as a key or value.***

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {

    //HashMap<String, Integer> hash = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    Hashtable<String, Integer> hash = new Hashtable<String, Integer>();
    //ConcurrentHashMap<String, Integer> hash = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    
    new Thread() {
        @Override public void run() {
            try {
                for (int i = 10; i < 20; i++) {
                    sleepThread(1);
                    System.out.println("T1 :- Key"+i);
                    hash.put("Key"+i, i);
                }
                System.out.println( System.identityHashCode( hash ) );
            } catch ( Exception e ) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }.start();
    new Thread() {
        @Override public void run() {
            try {
                sleepThread(5);
                // ConcurrentHashMap  traverse using Iterator, Enumeration is Fail-Safe.
                
                // Hashtable traverse using Enumeration is Fail-Safe, Iterator is Fail-Fast.
                for (Enumeration<String> e = hash.keys(); e.hasMoreElements(); ) {
                    sleepThread(1);
                    System.out.println("T2 : "+ e.nextElement());
                }
                
                // HashMap traverse using Iterator, Enumeration is Fail-Fast.
                /*
                for (Iterator< Entry<String, Integer> > it = hash.entrySet().iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
                    sleepThread(1);
                    System.out.println("T2 : "+ it.next());
                    // ConcurrentModificationException at java.util.Hashtable$Enumerator.next
                }
                */
                
                /*
                Set< Entry<String, Integer> > entrySet = hash.entrySet();
                Iterator< Entry<String, Integer> > it = entrySet.iterator();
                Enumeration<Entry<String, Integer>> entryEnumeration = Collections.enumeration( entrySet );
                while( entryEnumeration.hasMoreElements() ) {
                    sleepThread(1);
                    Entry<String, Integer> nextElement = entryEnumeration.nextElement();
                    System.out.println("T2 : "+ nextElement.getKey() +" : "+ nextElement.getValue() );
                    //java.util.ConcurrentModificationException at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextNode
                    //                                          at java.util.HashMap$EntryIterator.next
                    //                                          at java.util.Collections$3.nextElement
                }
                */
            } catch ( Exception e ) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }.start();
    
    Map<String, String> unmodifiableMap = Collections.unmodifiableMap( map );
    try {
        unmodifiableMap.put("key4", "unmodifiableMap");
    } catch (java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException e) {
        System.err.println("UnsupportedOperationException : "+ e.getMessage() );
    }
}
static void sleepThread( int sec ) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep( 1000 * sec );
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**«** **Null Keys And Null Values**

`HashMap` allows maximum one null key and any number of null values. Where as `Hashtable` doesn’t allow even a single null key and null value, if the key or value null is then it throws NullPointerException. <sup>[Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31243387/5081877)</sup>

**«** **Synchronized, Thread Safe**

`Hashtable` is internally synchronized. Therefore, it is very much safe to use `Hashtable` in multi threaded applications. Where as `HashMap` is not internally synchronized. Therefore, it is not safe to use `HashMap` in multi threaded applications without external synchronization. You can externally synchronize `HashMap` using `Collections.synchronizedMap()` method.

**«** **Performance**

As `Hashtable` is internally synchronized, this makes `Hashtable` slightly slower than the `HashMap`.

---

@See

- [A red–black tree is a kind of self-balancing binary search tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree)
- [Performance Improvement for `HashMap` in Java 8](https://www.nagarro.com/de/perspectives/post/24/performance-improvement-for-hashmap-in-java-8)

Answer (score 21):

For threaded apps, you can often get away with ConcurrentHashMap- depends on your performance requirements.

Answer (score 20):

1.`Hashmap` and `HashTable` both store key and value.

2.`Hashmap` can store one key as `null`. `Hashtable` can't store `null`.

3.`HashMap` is not synchronized but `Hashtable` is synchronized.

4.`HashMap` can be synchronized with `Collection.SyncronizedMap(map)`

```
Map hashmap = new HashMap();

Map map = Collections.SyncronizedMap(hashmap);
```

Answer (score 19):

Apart from the differences already mentioned, it should be noted that since Java 8, `HashMap` dynamically replaces the Nodes (linked list) used in each bucket with TreeNodes (red-black tree), so that even if high hash collisions exist, the worst case *when searching* is

O(log(n)) for `HashMap` **Vs** O(n) in `Hashtable`.

*The aforementioned improvement has not been applied to `Hashtable` yet, but only to `HashMap`, `LinkedHashMap`, and `ConcurrentHashMap`.

FYI, currently,

- `TREEIFY_THRESHOLD = 8` : if a bucket contains more than 8 nodes, the linked list is transformed into a balanced tree.
- `UNTREEIFY_THRESHOLD = 6` : when a bucket becomes too small (due to removal or resizing) the tree is converted back to linked list.

Comment: Of course, this tree only helps when the hash codes of the keys are actually different and just fall into the same bucket, not when you actually get many keys with the same hash code.

Answer (score 17):

There are 5 basic differentiations with HashTable and HashMaps.

1. Maps allows you to iterate and retrieve keys, values, and both key-value pairs as well, Where HashTable don't have all this capability.
2. In Hashtable there is a function contains(), which is very confusing to use. Because the meaning of contains is slightly deviating. Whether it means contains key or contains  value? tough to understand. Same thing in Maps we have ContainsKey() and ContainsValue() functions, which are very easy to understand.
3. In hashmap you can remove element while iterating, safely. where as it is not possible in hashtables.
4. HashTables are by default synchronized, so it can be used with multiple threads easily. Where as HashMaps are not synchronized by default, so can be used with only single thread.  But you can still convert HashMap to synchronized by using Collections util class's synchronizedMap(Map m) function.
5. HashTable won't allow null keys or null values. Where as HashMap allows one null key, and multiple null values.

Answer (score 14):

HashMap: It is a class available inside java.util package and it is used to store the element in key and value format.

Hashtable: It is a legacy class which is being recognized inside collection framework.

Answer (score 14):

My small contribution :

> 1. First and most significant different between `Hashtable` and `HashMap` is that, `HashMap` is not thread-safe  while `Hashtable` is a thread-safe collection.
> 2. Second important difference between `Hashtable` and `HashMap` is performance, since `HashMap` is not synchronized it perform better than `Hashtable`.
> 3. Third difference on `Hashtable` vs `HashMap` is that `Hashtable` is obsolete class and you should be using `ConcurrentHashMap` in place of `Hashtable` in Java.

Answer (score 13):

1. `Hashtable` is synchronized whereas `HashMap` is not.
2. Another difference is that iterator in the `HashMap` is fail-safe
   while the enumerator for the `Hashtable` isn't. If you change the map
   while iterating, you'll know.
3. `HashMap` permits null values in it, while `Hashtable` doesn't.

Comment: HashMap iterator is fail-fast not fail-safe. Thats why we have ConcurrentHashMap that allows modification while iteration. Check this post http://www.journaldev.com/122/hashmap-vs-concurrenthashmap-%e2%80%93-example-and-exploring-iterator

Answer (score 13):

[HashTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html) is a legacy class in the jdk that shouldn't be used anymore. Replace usages of it with [ConcurrentHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html). If you don't require thread safety, use [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) which isn't [threadsafe](http://jsr-305.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/javax/annotation/concurrent/ThreadSafe.html) but faster and uses less memory.

Comment: Because I thought the other answers, at the time, didn't dismiss HashTable but explained that it was threadsafe. The truth is that as soon as you see HashTable in code, you should replace it with ConcurrentHashMap without skipping a beat. And if thread safety is not a concern then HashMap can be used to improve performance a bit.

Answer (score 13):

**HashMap** and **Hashtable** both are used to store data in key and value form. Both are using hashing technique to store unique keys.
ut there are many differences between HashMap and Hashtable classes that are given below.

[image]

Answer (score 12):

**HashMap and HashTable**

- Some important points about HashMap and HashTable.
     please read below details.

1) Hashtable and Hashmap implement the java.util.Map interface
2) Both Hashmap and Hashtable is the hash based collection. and working on hashing.
so these are similarity of HashMap and HashTable.

- What is the difference between HashMap and HashTable?

1) First difference is HashMap is not thread safe While HashTable is ThreadSafe
2) HashMap is performance wise better because it is not thread safe. while Hashtable performance wise is not better because it is thread safe. so multiple thread can not access Hashtable at the same time.

Comment: Down-voted because this answer is not correct in some aspects. Hashtable does not implement the Map interface, but only extends the Dictionary class, which is obsolete.

Comment: @IoannisSermetziadis at least in the [Java 6 API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html), Hashtable also implements the Map interface.

Answer (score 10):

**`Hashtable:`**

**Hashtable** is a data structure that retains values of key-value pair. It doesn’t allow null for both the keys and the values. You will get a `NullPointerException` if you add null value. It is synchronized. So it comes with its cost. Only one thread can access **HashTable** at a particular time.

**Example** :

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Hashtable;

public class TestClass {

    public static void main(String args[ ]) {
    Map<Integer,String> states= new Hashtable<Integer,String>();
    states.put(1, "INDIA");
    states.put(2, "USA");

    states.put(3, null);    //will throw NullPointerEcxeption at runtime

    System.out.println(states.get(1));
    System.out.println(states.get(2));
//  System.out.println(states.get(3));

    }
}
```

**HashMap:**

**HashMap** is like **Hashtable** but it also accepts key value pair. It allows null for both the keys and the values. Its performance better is better than `HashTable`, because it is `unsynchronized`.

**Example:**

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class TestClass {

    public static void main(String args[ ]) {
    Map<Integer,String> states = new HashMap<Integer,String>();
    states.put(1, "INDIA");
    states.put(2, "USA");

    states.put(3, null);    // Okay
    states.put(null,"UK");

    System.out.println(states.get(1));
    System.out.println(states.get(2));
    System.out.println(states.get(3));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Since Hashtable in Java is a subclass of Dictionary class which is now obsolete due to the existence of Map Interface, it is not used anymore. Moreover, there isn't anything you can't do with a class that implements the Map Interface that you can do with a Hashtable.

Answer (score 7):

Old and classic topic, just want to add this helpful blog that explains this:

http://blog.manishchhabra.com/2012/08/the-5-main-differences-betwen-hashmap-and-hashtable/

Blog by Manish Chhabra

> The 5 main differences betwen HashMap and Hashtable
>
> HashMap and Hashtable both implement java.util.Map interface but there
>   are some differences that Java developers must understand to write
>   more efficient code. As of the Java 2 platform v1.2, Hashtable class
>   was retrofitted to implement the Map interface, making it a member of
>   the Java Collections Framework.
>
> 1. One of the major differences between HashMap and Hashtable is that HashMap is non-synchronized whereas Hashtable is synchronized, which
>      means Hashtable is thread-safe and can be shared between multiple
>      threads but HashMap cannot be shared between multiple threads without
>      proper synchronization. Java 5 introduced ConcurrentHashMap which is
>      an alternative of Hashtable and provides better scalability than
>      Hashtable in Java.Synchronized means only one thread can modify a hash
>      table at one point of time. Basically, it means that any thread before
>      performing an update on a hashtable will have to acquire a lock on the
>      object while others will wait for lock to be released.
> 2. The HashMap class is roughly equivalent to Hashtable, except that it permits nulls. (HashMap allows null values as key and value whereas
>      Hashtable doesn’t allow nulls).
> 3. The third significant difference between HashMap vs Hashtable is that Iterator in the HashMap is a fail-fast iterator while the
>      enumerator for the Hashtable is not and throw
>      ConcurrentModificationException if any other Thread modifies the map
>      structurally by adding or removing any element except Iterator’s own
>      remove() method. But this is not a guaranteed behavior and will be
>      done by JVM on best effort. This is also an important difference
>      between Enumeration and Iterator in Java.
> 4. One more notable difference between Hashtable and HashMap is that because of thread-safety and synchronization Hashtable is much slower
>      than HashMap if used in Single threaded environment. So if you don’t
>      need synchronization and HashMap is only used by one thread, it out
>      perform Hashtable in Java.
> 5. HashMap does not guarantee that the order of the map will remain constant over time.
>
> Note that HashMap can be synchronized by
>
> ```
> Map m = Collections.synchronizedMap(hashMap);
> ```
>
> In Summary there are significant differences between Hashtable and
>   HashMap in Java e.g. thread-safety and speed and based upon that only
>   use Hashtable if you absolutely need thread-safety, if you are running
>   Java 5 consider using ConcurrentHashMap in Java.

Comment: ConcurrentHashMap is not read-synchronized, whereas Hashtable is.  So if you have a high amount of read operations happening simultaneously with writes, a Hashtable would serve you better if you care about data integrity.

Answer (score 6):

**Synchronization or Thread Safe** :

Hash Map is not synchronized hence it is not thred safe and it cannot be shared between multiple threads without proper synchronized block whereas, Hashtable is synchronized and hence it is thread safe.

**Null keys and null values** :

HashMap allows one null key and any number of null values.Hashtable does not allow null keys or values.

**Iterating the values**:

Iterator in the HashMap is a fail-fast iterator while the enumerator for the Hashtable is not and throw ConcurrentModificationException if any other Thread modifies the map structurally by adding or removing any element except Iterator’s own remove() method.

**Superclass and Legacy** :

HashMap is subclass of AbstractMap class whereas Hashtable is subclass of Dictionary class.

**Performance** :

As HashMap is not synchronized it is faster as compared to Hashtable.

Refer http://modernpathshala.com/Article/1020/difference-between-hashmap-and-hashtable-in-java for examples and interview questions and quiz related to  Java collection

Answer (score 5):

`HashMap` is emulated and therefore usable in `GWT client code` whereas `Hashtable` is not.

Answer (score 3):

HashMaps gives you freedom of synchronization and debugging is lot more easier

Answer (score 3):

HashMap is a class  used to store the element in key and value format.it is not thread safe.
because it is not synchronized .where as Hashtable is synchronized.Hashmap permits null but hastable doesn't permit null.

Answer (score 1):

The Hashtable class is synchronized, that is, it is designed to be used by applications that handle multiple or multithreaded process. Synchronized classes are less efficient in the classical case of an application to a process, so the Hashmap class is faster in general.
The HashTable class does not accept the Null value, either for keys or for values, while the HashMap class allows a single key with Null and as many as null as possible.