# What's the difference between Hashtable and Dictionary?

Tags: java, dictionary, collections, hashtable

What's the difference between `Dictionary` and `Hashtable` and how do I work with the `Dictionary` class in Java?

Comment: There is a lot of good stuff in google - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/implementations/index.html

Comment: And on stackoverflow - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/267312/difference-between-a-hashmap-and-a-dictionary-adt

Comment: If you have a choice, you should use `Map` instead of `Dictionary`, which is obsolete.

Comment: Hashtable is synchronized(thread safe) form of HashMap.

Comment: @kundanbora You can use ConcurrentHashMap if you need thread safety

Comment: Although these data structures are thread safe but using these doesn't mean that your code is thread safe. you have to implement your own synchronization yourself to make code completely thread safe.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`Dictionary` is an abstract base class of `Hashtable`. Both are still in JDK for backwards compatibility with old code. We are expected to use `HashMap` and other implementations of `Map` interface introduced in Java 1.2.

Comment: Worth mentioning that Hashtable is thread safe, whereas HashMap is not. See my answer.

Comment: Hashtable has been retrofitted to implement Map.

Answer (score 16):

The javadoc for [Dictionary](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Dictionary.html) has your answer.

> The Dictionary class is the abstract parent of any class, such as Hashtable, which maps keys to values.

You don't work directly with `Dictionary`, since it is an `abstract` class.

Also note the following from the same documentation:

> **NOTE: This class is obsolete. New implementations should implement the [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) interface, rather than extending this class.**

Answer (score 12):

`Dictionary` is an abstract class, superclass of `Hashtable`.
You should not use `Dictionary` as it is [obsolete](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Dictionary.html).
As for Hashtable, the advantage it had over other maps such as `HashMap` was thread safety, but with the introduction of ConcurrentHashMap since Java 1.5, there is no real reason to use it any longer - see [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html)

> As of the Java 2 platform v1.2, this class was retrofitted to implement the Map interface, making it a member of the Java Collections Framework. Unlike the new collection implementations, Hashtable is synchronized. If a thread-safe implementation is not needed, it is recommended to use HashMap in place of Hashtable. If a thread-safe highly-concurrent implementation is desired, then it is recommended to use ConcurrentHashMap in place of Hashtable.

**In summary**: Don't use `Dictionary` or `Hashtable`, unless you really have to for compatibility reasons, use either `HashMap` if you don't need thread safety, or `ConcurrentHashMap` if your map is used in a concurrent environment.

Answer (score 3):

`Hashtable` is an implementation of `Dictionary`. You can't use `Dictionary` directly because it's an abstract class.

But you shouldn't use either because they have been superceded by the `Map` interface and the implementing classes, of which [`HashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) is the most popular.

Answer (score 2):

I've found a lecture on Principles of OOP that contains the answer you seek:

> http://www.clear.rice.edu/comp202/04-fall/lectures/lec23/

EDIT:

> **Dictionary**
>   A major theme in computing is the theme of storage/retrieval/removal: store data somewhere so that it can later be retrieved and discarded if no longer needed, all of this in the most efficient manner.  The abstraction of these computing activities is embodied in the notion of what is called a dictionary, expressed in Java as an interface as follows.
>
> **Hash Tables**
>       A hash table is a generalization of an ordinary array.
>       When the number of keys actually stored is small relative to the total number of possible keys, hash tables become an effective
>   alternative to directly addressing an array, since a hash table
>   typically uses an array of size proportional to the number of keys
>   actually stored.
>       Instead of using the key as an array index directly, the array index is computed from the key.
>       With hashing, an element with key k is stored in slot h(k); i.e., a hash function h is used to compute the slot from the key k.
>       h maps the set U of keys into the slots of a hash table T[0..m-1]:
>           h:U -> {0, 1, ..., m - 1}

Answer (score 2):

The Dictionary class is the abstract parent of any class, such as Hashtable, which maps keys to values. Every key and every value is an object. In any one Dictionary object, every key is associated with at most one value. Given a Dictionary and a key, the associated element can be looked up. Any non-null object can be used as a key and as a value.

Answer (score 1):

According to the javadocs for Dictionary:

> NOTE: This class is obsolete. New implementations should implement the
>   Map interface, rather than extending this class.

Hashtable is JDK 1.0 vintage, too.  You should prefer the Map interface and its more modern implementations: HashMap and TreeMap.