# What is the difference between the Dictionary class and the Map class in Java?

Tags: java, dictionary

I was just seeing the [difference between a HashMap and HashTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40471/differences-between-hashmap-and-hashtable). Other than the obvious synchronized and unsynchronized difference, I noticed that [`HashTable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html) extends the `Dictionary` class while [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) implements [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html). Both of them store `<Key, Value>` pair, so what's the difference. I tried Googling for it and I found few questions on SO ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2884068/what-is-the-difference-between-a-map-and-a-dictionary), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9769797/java-whats-difference-between-hashtable-and-dictionary) and [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267312/difference-between-a-hashmap-and-a-dictionary-adt)). I didn't find anything satisfactory other than the fact that `Dictionary` class is obsolete. Is there any difference between thee two classes? If no, why is the dictionary class obsolete now?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Differences between HashMap and Hashtable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40471/differences-between-hashmap-and-hashtable)

Comment: Don't think it is a duplicate, no.  This is querying the difference between Dictionary and Map, which is a somewhat different question.  Some of the answers there touch on the fact that there is a difference, but none go into the important question of why Dictionary is obsolete.

Comment: It's not clear how your question differs from those existing questions.

Comment: @Jules HashMap implements Map, HashTable extends Dictionary. It's fundamentally the same question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java What's difference between Hashtable and Dictionary?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9769797/java-whats-difference-between-hashtable-and-dictionary)

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Not really, no.  The answers to the question of differences between HashMap and Hashtable predominantly relate to the *implementation* of those classes.  This question, by focussing on the abstract ancestors, is asking more about the difference in the *interface*.

Comment: It's worth noting that Java has lots of redundant classes and interfaces, for historical reasons.  When an older class/interface seems to duplicate a newer one don't spend too much time wondering why, as usually the newer stuff was created to fit together better in some grand scheme. Functionally there's usually very little difference.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`Dictionary` is an abstract class that contains no non-abstract methods.  Modern practice strongly recommends using an interface rather than a class in such a case.  `Map` is such an interface.

It also uses `Enumeration` which is also considered obsolete; `Map` uses `Iterator` which is not.

Answer (score 2):

- `Dictionary` is an abstract class whereas `Map` is an interface, hence it is more Java-idiomatic.
- `Dictionary` [was deprecated early in Java 1.2](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~cs368-2/JavaTutorial/jdk1.2/api/) and replaced by its better interface counterpart, `Map`. This leads to believed that `Dictionary` was just a bad design choice and the Java folks kept the `Dictionary` class for backward compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

The main difference is that Dictionary is an abstract class and Map is a interface.
Collections API uses interfaces like Map, List, Set.

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary is an abstract base class of Hashtable. Both are still in JDK for backwards compatibility with old code. We are expected to use HashMap and other implementations of Map interface introduced in Java 1.2.