# Java: how to convert HashMap<String, Object> to array

Tags: java, arrays, collections, hashmap

I need to convert a `HashMap<String, Object>` to an array; could anyone show me how it's done?

Comment: you want the keys, the values, or both?

Answer (score 222, accepted):

```java
hashMap.keySet().toArray(); // returns an array of keys
hashMap.values().toArray(); // returns an array of values
```

---

## Edit

It should be noted that the ordering of both arrays may not be the same,
See oxbow_lakes answer for a better approach for iteration when the pair key/values are needed.

Comment: Actually, this code offers no guarantee that hashMap.keySet().toArray()[0] will be the original key for hashMap.values().toArray()[0] from the original Map. So this is extremely *dangerous*

Comment: @CrackerJack9 can you explain?

Comment: The keys wont correspond to their values across the two arrays.

Comment: @Jakobud landon9720 is correct...the order is psuedo-random, and it cannot be guaranteed that key[0] will correspond to value[0] after you convert the keys to a `Set` and the values to a `Collection`. While they are technically converted to arrays (and answers your question), the concept of the key-value pair has been lost - which is why this is a very misleading (and dangerous) answer....

Comment: I can attest to the danger of this code snippet. When I wrote it, my terminal reached out and slapped me. Extremely dangerous! Beware!

Answer (score 76):

If you want the keys and values, you can always do this via the `entrySet`:

```
hashMap.entrySet().toArray(); // returns a Map.Entry<K,V>[]
```

From each entry you can (of course) get both the key *and* value via the `getKey` and `getValue` methods

Comment: @CrackerJack9 No, it works. Unlike the accepted solution, this one maintains the key-value pairs. You get `{key, value}[]` as opposed to `key[], value[]`

Comment: This seems a better solution

Answer (score 63):

If you have `HashMap<String, SomeObject> hashMap` then:

```java
hashMap.values().toArray();
```

Will return an `Object[]`. If instead you want an array of the type `SomeObject`, you could use:

```java
hashMap.values().toArray(new SomeObject[0]);
```

Comment: I think you mean `values()` instead of `keySet()` for an array of `SomeObject`.

Comment: @Alex "In older Java versions using pre-sized array was recommended (...) However since late updates of OpenJDK 6 this call was intrinsified, making the performance of the empty array version the same and sometimes even better, compared to the pre-sized version. Also passing pre-sized array is dangerous for a concurrent or synchronized collection as a data race is possible between the size and toArray call which may result in extra nulls at the end of the array, if the collection was concurrently shrunk during the operation."

- intellij

Answer (score 31):

To guarantee the correct order for each array of Keys and Values, use this (the other answers use individual `Set`s which offer no guarantee as to order.

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
String[] keys = new String[map.size()];
Object[] values = new Object[map.size()];
int index = 0;
for (Map.Entry<String, Object> mapEntry : map.entrySet()) {
    keys[index] = mapEntry.getKey();
    values[index] = mapEntry.getValue();
    index++;
}
```

Comment: perfect! we get both key and value, with auto types fill in eclipse, long time looking for this, thx!

Answer (score 12):

An alternative to CrackerJacks suggestion, if you want the HashMap to maintain order you could consider using a LinkedHashMap instead. As far as im aware it's functionality is identical to a HashMap but it is FIFO so it maintains the order in which items were added.

Answer (score 8):

I used almost the same as @kmccoy, but instead of a `keySet()` I did this

```
hashMap.values().toArray(new MyObject[0]);
```

Answer (score 7):

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("key1", "value1");
map.put("key2", "value2");

Object[][] twoDarray = new Object[map.size()][2];

Object[] keys = map.keySet().toArray();
Object[] values = map.values().toArray();

for (int row = 0; row < twoDarray.length; row++) {
    twoDarray[row][0] = keys[row];
    twoDarray[row][1] = values[row];
}

// Print out the new 2D array
for (int i = 0; i < twoDarray.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < twoDarray[i].length; j++) {
        System.out.println(twoDarray[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

If you are using Java 8+ and need a 2 dimensional `Array`, perhaps for TestNG data providers, you can try:

```
map.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .map(e -> new Object[]{e.getKey(), e.getValue()})
    .toArray(Object[][]::new);
```

If your `Object`s are `String`s and you need a `String[][]`, try:

```
map.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .map(e -> new String[]{e.getKey(), e.getValue().toString()})
    .toArray(String[][]::new);
```

Answer (score 3):

To Get in One Dimension Array.

```
    String[] arr1 = new String[hashmap.size()];
    String[] arr2 = new String[hashmap.size()];
    Set entries = hashmap.entrySet();
    Iterator entriesIterator = entries.iterator();

    int i = 0;
    while(entriesIterator.hasNext()){

        Map.Entry mapping = (Map.Entry) entriesIterator.next();

        arr1[i] = mapping.getKey().toString();
        arr2[i] = mapping.getValue().toString();

        i++;
    }
```

To Get in two Dimension Array.

```
   String[][] arr = new String[hashmap.size()][2];
   Set entries = hashmap.entrySet();
   Iterator entriesIterator = entries.iterator();

   int i = 0;
   while(entriesIterator.hasNext()){

    Map.Entry mapping = (Map.Entry) entriesIterator.next();

    arr[i][0] = mapping.getKey().toString();
    arr[i][1] = mapping.getValue().toString();

    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In the case keys and values are strings and you want to alternate key and value in the same array:

```
String[] result = myMap.entrySet()
                       .stream()
                       .flatMap(entry -> Stream.of(entry.getKey(),entry.getValue()))
                       .toArray(String[]::new);
// result = {key_1, value_1, key_2, value_2 ...}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this too.

```
public static String[][] getArrayFromHash(Hashtable<String,String> data){
        String[][] str = null;
        {
            Object[] keys = data.keySet().toArray();
            Object[] values = data.values().toArray();
            str = new String[keys.length][values.length];
            for(int i=0;i<keys.length;i++) {
                str[0][i] = (String)keys[i];
                str[1][i] = (String)values[i];
            }
        }
        return str;
    }
```

Here I am using String as return type. You may change it to required return type by you.

Comment: the question is about `HashMap()` but your solution is about `Hashtable()`... There are some [differences](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40878/3595288) between them

Answer (score 0):

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <E,T> E[] hashMapKeysToArray(HashMap<E,T> map)
    {
        int s;
        if(map == null || (s = map.size())<1)
            return null;

        E[] temp;
        E typeHelper;
        try
        {
            Iterator<Entry<E, T>> iterator = map.entrySet().iterator();
            Entry<E, T> iK = iterator.next();
            typeHelper = iK.getKey();

            Object o = Array.newInstance(typeHelper.getClass(), s);
            temp = (E[]) o;

            int index = 0;
            for (Map.Entry<E,T> mapEntry : map.entrySet())
            {
                temp[index++] = mapEntry.getKey();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return null;
        }
        return temp;
    }
//--------------------------------------------------------
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <E,T> T[] hashMapValuesToArray(HashMap<E,T> map)
    {
        int s;
        if(map == null || (s = map.size())<1)
            return null;

        T[] temp;
        T typeHelper;
        try
        {
            Iterator<Entry<E, T>> iterator = map.entrySet().iterator();
            Entry<E, T> iK = iterator.next();
            typeHelper = iK.getValue();

            Object o = Array.newInstance(typeHelper.getClass(), s);
            temp = (T[]) o;

            int index = 0;
            for (Map.Entry<E,T> mapEntry : map.entrySet())
            {
                temp[index++] = mapEntry.getValue();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {return null;}

        return temp;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
String[] stringValues= new String[hashMap.values().size()];
hashMap.values().toArray(stringValues);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you need to pass values to an array of objects try:

```
Array:
Object[] object= hashMap.values().toArray(new Object[0]);

Arraylist:
ArrayList<Object> object=new ArrayList<>(hashMap.values());
```