# convert a hashmap to an array

Tags: java, arrays, hashmap

I have a hashmap like this:

```
HashMap<String, String[]> map = new HashMap<String, String[]>();
```

I want to convert this to an array, say Temp[], containing as first value the key from the hashmap and as second the String[]-array from the map, also as array. Is this possible? How?

Comment: Your question isn't clear - are you talking about an array of a new class, where each instance contains the key and value from the map?

Answer (score 5):

See same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090556/java-how-to-convert-hashmapstring-object-to-array):

```
hashMap.keySet().toArray(); // returns an array of keys
hashMap.values().toArray(); // returns an array of values
```

Comment: code is like this by now: ` HashMap<String, String[]> map = new HashMap<String, String[]>();
map.put("key1", new String[]{"value1", "test1"});
map.put("key2", new String[]{"value2"});

Object[][] twoDarray = new String[map.size()][];

Object[] keys = map.keySet().toArray();
Object[] values = map.values().toArray();

System.out.println(values[1]);
System.out.println(values[2]);` 
output is broken. gives back [Ljava.lang.String;@1f33675
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
 at test.main(test.java:17)

Comment: @tetsuya You are trying to access the third element backed in the Values() HashSet, which according to your input **doesnt exist**, hence u get that RuntimeException

Comment: @tetsuya Index in arrays are starting at 0. So you can access only values[0] and values[1] if you have 2 entries in your map.

Answer (score 1):

Hm. Your question is really strange, but here is what you asked:

```
HashMap<String, String[]> map = new HashMap<String, String[]>();
String[] keys = map.keySet().toArray();
Object[] result = new Object[keys.length*2]; //the array that should hold all the values as requested
for(int i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
  result[i] = keys[i]; //put the next key into the array
  result[i+1] = map.get(keys[i]); //put the next String[] in the array, according to the key.
}
```

But man, for what should you ever need something like this? Whatever you want to do, The chance is over 99% that you don't need to write something like this...

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you just need to write a method, that does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you needed but here is your code that I modified:

```
    Map<String, String[]> map = new HashMap<String, String[]>();
    map.put("key1", new String[]{"value1", "test1"});
    map.put("key2", new String[]{"value2"});

    Object[] keys = map.keySet().toArray();
    Object[] values = map.values().toArray();

    System.out.println("key = " + keys[0] + ", value #1 = " + ((Object[])values[0])[0]);
    System.out.println("key = " + keys[1] + ", value #1 = " + ((Object[])values[1])[0] + ", value #2 = " + ((Object[])values[1])[1]);
```

Output:

```
key = key2, value #1 = value2
key = key1, value #1 = value1, value #2 = test1
```

Note that under `key[0]` you have `"key2"` instead of `"key1"`. That is because `HashMap` doesn't keep the keys in the same order you add them. To change that you must choose another `Map` implementation (for example `TreeMap` if you want to have alphabetical order).

How this works? Java allows you to cast arrays to `Object`. `toArray()` method returns `Object[]` - an array of `Objects`, but those objects are also arrays (of String - as you defined in your map)! If you print just `value[0]` it would be like printing `mySampleArray` where `mySampleArray` is:

```
Object[] mySampleArray = new Object[5];
```

So you call it on the whole array not an element. This is why you get `[Ljava.lang.String;@7c6768` etc. (which is className@HashCode - thats what default `toString()` method does).

In order to get to your element you have to go deeper.

```
((Object[])values[0])[0]
```

This means: Take values[0] (we know it holds an array), cast it to array and take first element.

I hope this helps, please let me know if you need any additional info.