# ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> to String[]

Tags: java, android, string, arraylist, hashmap

i have data fetched from my webservice in

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>
```

Now i want to convert each object of the above to

```
String[]
```

how do i do this? 
any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: it contains data obtained from a webservice serving json data. i need to extract each field as a string array for populating them into different views like viwepagers and list views.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090556/java-how-to-convert-hashmapstring-object-to-array.check this might help.

Comment: In the array you want to put hashmap's keys, values or both?

Comment: Please cover my tutorial on internal life of HashMap,ArrayList and other Java collection types [here](http://volodial.blogspot.com/search/label/Java%20Collections)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> test = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
HashMap<String, String> n = new HashMap<String, String>();
n.put("a", "a");
n.put("b", "b");
test.add(n);

HashMap<String, String> m = test.get(0);//it will get the first HashMap Stored in array list 

String strArr[] = new String[m.size()];
int i = 0;
for (HashMap<String, String> hash : test) {
    for (String current : hash.values()) {
        strArr[i] = current;
        i++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The uses for an Hashmap should be an Index of HashValues for finding the values much faster. I don't know why you have Key and Values as Strings but if you only need the values you can do it like that:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> test = new ArrayList<>();
String sum = "";
for (HashMap<String, String> hash : test) {
    for (String current : hash.values()) {
        sum = sum + current + "<#>";
    }
}
String[] arr = sum.split("<#>");
```

It's not a nice way but the request isn't it too ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
 ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> meterList = controller.getMeter();

HashMap<String, String> mtiti = meterList.get(0);//it will get the first HashMap Stored in array list

String[] strMeter = new String[mtiti.size()];

String meter = "";
for (HashMap<String, String> hash : meterList) {
    for (String current : hash.values()) {
        meter = meter + current + "<#>";
    }
}
String[] arr = meter.split("<#>");
```