# How I can convert the hashmap to array?

Tags: android, arrays, hashmap

I want hashmap to array

I create the hashmap

```
Map<Integer,File> selectedFiles = new Hashmap<>();
```

and put it some Map data

And I convert this hashmap's values to array so

```
File[] files = (File[]) selectedFiles.values().toArray();
```

But errors occur;

```
java.lang.Object[] cannot be cast to java.io.File[]
```

I know that when I want the hashmap's values to array, use .values.toArray() but maybe it is not corret;

This way is wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The easiest way to transform collection to array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3293946/the-easiest-way-to-transform-collection-to-array)

Comment: Unless you have other reasons, Android advice is to use [SparseArray<File>](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseArray.html) instead of Map<Integer, File>: less boxing, lower memory usage.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: how to convert HashMap<String, Object> to array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090556/java-how-to-convert-hashmapstring-object-to-array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Map<Integer, File> selectedFiles = new HashMap<>();
    selectedFiles.put(1, null);

    File[] files = selectedFiles.values().toArray(
            new File[selectedFiles.size()]);

    System.out.println(files);// We will get the object [Ljava.io.File;@15db9742
```

arrays. toArray without parameters creates an object array because the type information of the list is lost at runtime.

Comment: Thanks you save my time

Answer (score 0):

Please use below Code to convert HashMap to Array ,You can change String to File in your case.

```
   //Creating a HashMap object

    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

    //Getting Collection of values from HashMap

    Collection<String> values = map.values();

    //Creating an ArrayList of values

    ArrayList<String> listOfValues = new ArrayList<String>(values);

   // Convert ArrayList to Array

   String stringArray[]=listOfValues.toArray(new String[listOfValues.size()])
```

Comment: You can skip the intermediate `ArrayList`. Also, why not just use `File`?

Comment: @4castle Yes,  you are right  and I just put  sample code  to do this that's why using String .