# remove key from hash table

Tags: java

I want to remove key from hash Table without using the remove function. so give me some idea.

Comment: And why would you want to do that?

Comment: what's wrong with the `remove()` _method_?

Comment: Maybe Datta wants to remove entries while iterating through the entryset. And remove throws ugly exceptions.

Comment: why would you ever do this, except for homework?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can call `remove()` on an `Iterator` instead of on the `Hashtable` itself:

```
Hashtable<String, String> map = new Hashtable<String, String>();
map.put("one", "een");
map.put("two", "twee");
map.put("three", "drie");

for (Iterator<Map.Entry<String, String>> i = map.entrySet().iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
    Map.Entry<String, String> entry = i.next();

    if ("two".equals(entry.getKey())) {
        // Removes entry from Hashtable; note, this is not the Hashtable.remove() method
        // but the Iterator.remove() method
        i.remove();
    }
}

System.out.println(map);
```

(NOTE: You should use `HashMap` instead of the legacy collection class `Hashtable`).

Answer (score 10):

You can emulate removed keys by supplementing a `Map<K,V> map` with a `Set<K> removedKeys`.

To remove a `key`, just `removedKeys.add(key);`.

Whenever a `K key` is queried, you see if `removedKeys.contains(key)`. If it does, then `key` has effectively been "removed" from `map`.

Note that this is a very peculiar way of doing things, and keeping the two structures in sync may cause later headaches. It's more acceptable if `removedKeys` is localized and short-lived, e.g. when you're iterating over the entries of a `Map` using `for-each` and want to remove some keys later, while avoiding [`ConcurrentModificationException`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html).

So you may have something like this:

```
static void removeEvenKeys(Map<Integer,String> map) {
    Set<Integer> removedKeys = new HashSet<Integer>();
    for (Map.Entry<Integer,String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getKey() %2 == 0) {
            removedKeys.add(entry.getKey());
        }
    }
    map.keySet().removeAll(removedKeys);        
}
```

And then elsewhere:

```
    Map<Integer,String> map = new HashMap<Integer,String>();
    map.put(1, "One");
    map.put(2, "Two");
    map.put(3, "Three");
    map.put(4, "Four");

    removeEvenKeys(map);
    System.out.println(map);
    // "{1=One, 3=Three}"
```

#### See also

- *Effective Java 2nd Edition, Item 52: Refer to objects by their interfaces*

#### Related questions

- [Java hashmap vs hashtable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40471/java-hashmap-vs-hashtable)
- [Java: Efficient Equivalent to Removing while Iterating a Collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223918/java-efficient-equivalent-to-removing-while-iterating-a-collection)