# What is Java equivalent for PHP array with non-numeric keys?

Tags: java, php, arrays, hashmap

What would be Java equivalent for php array like this:

```
$user = array("name" => "John", "email" => "john@mail.com");
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a [HashMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) or a [Hashtable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html). Not sure which one to use? Read the API or check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40471/java-hashmap-vs-hashtable) which discusses the pros and cons of each.

```
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("name", "John");
map.put("email", "john@mail.com");
```

Comment: IMHO Hashtable was replaced by HashMap in Java 1.2. It is retained for legacy support.

Comment: @Peter - I tend to agree with you. I've changed my link to a SO question of HashMap vs Hashtable (which comes down on the side of HashMap) instead.

Answer (score 6):

An implementation of the Map interface is the Java equivalent of an associative array, but it seems like what you really want is a User class with fields for name and email.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I would have User class, of course. My idea is to have something like array with primitive types or strings so that I could pass that array to a class that does not know about the type of the original object.

Answer (score 6):

Keep in mind that PHP's associative arrays keep track of the order they were inserted. So if you use `foreach` to iterate over their keys, you'll get them in the same order.

The closest Java equivalent is probably [LinkedHashMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html).

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you use LinkedHashMap. Its main advantage over HashMap its that it retains the order the keys were added. For HashMap they appear in a pseudo random order which makes reading them much harder.

```
Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
map.put("name", "John");
map.put("email", "john@mail.com");
```

Answer (score 2):

It's called java.util.HashMap

Answer (score 1):

Try http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Map.html, or more specifically a http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html.

Answer (score 1):

```
Map user = new HashMap();
user.put("name", "John");
user.put("email", "john@mail.com");
```