# Is this correct usage of a hashtable in Java

Tags: java, hashtable

```
package datastrcutures;
import java.util.*;

public class java_hashtable {
      public static void ratingofcity() {
           Hashtable CityRating = new Hashtable();
           CityRating.put("New York", "8");
           CityRating.put("Sandton", "9");
      }

}
```

Comment: And what you actually want to do with this code? Is the value ("8", "9") going to be unique?

Comment: Out of convention variable name should be cityRating and not CityRating.

Comment: And you might think about renaming the package to `datastructures`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have a typo there, your object type has to be `Hashtable` instead of `Hasttable` And you should use [Java Generics](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html)

Instantiate your hash table object like this:

```
Hashtable<String, String> cityRating = new Hashtable<String, String>();
```

And as Java naming convention I would suggest having your object name start with a lower case letter.

Comment: And have a look at HashMap. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40471/java-hashmap-vs-hashtable

Answer (score 2):

The question `Is this correct usage of a hashtable` is very subjective.
A `Map` is used to storing sets of keys and values like in your example.
However - things you should consider in your design:

- Do I need my map to be Thread-Safe? if not, use a **HashMap**
- Can you have the same rating for two cities? If not, maybe an array would be better?
- If the answer to the above question is "**yes**" - do you need to get all the cities with the same rating? at which case you might need to come up with another data structure, or simply maintain two maps (one of **City -> Rating** and one of **Rating -> City**)
- Is the rating OK with being a `String` - wouldn't you prefer an `Integer` so you can compare them?

Also, a few notes not related to the "design" of this question:

- Prefer declaring the interface of the **Collection** you use instead of the implementation - it makes code changes easier and makes your API more robust.
- Use generics - it makes code type safe and easier to read. e.g. `Map<String, Integer> cityRatings = new Hashtable<String, Integer>();`

Answer (score 0):

```
 import java.util.*;

public class java_hashtable {
  public static void ratingofcity() {
       Hashtable<String, String> cityRating = new Hashtable<String, String>();
       CityRating.put("New York", "8");
       CityRating.put("Sandton", "9");
  }

}
```

Hashtable is declared in a wrong way. The changes which I made must work now.