# Inheritance and static members in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, static, custom-exceptions

I am working on a project which contains a couple of modules. I want to provide the ability in every module to have a custom exception that statically populates internal structure, e.g. HashMap, from property file with custom error_code-error_message pairs. 
I have a base abstract custom exception what contains a static property:

```
public abstract class AbstractException extends RuntimeException{
   public static Map<String, String> ERRORS = new HashMap<String, String>();
   public String code;
   // getters and setter for code ommited

   public static init(String fileName, Class<?> clazz){
    // read properties file
    // populate map
   }

   public static String getMessageByCode(String code){
    //
   String mess = ERRORS.get(code);
   // in case of null message provide default message about unknown error
   }

   public AbstractException(String code){
      super(getMessageByCode(code));
      this.setCode(code);
   }

   public AbstractException(Throwable thr){
      super(getMessageByCode("ERROR_999"), thr);
      this.setCode(code);
   }

   public AbstractException(Throwable thr, String msg){
      super(getMessageByCode("ERROR_999") + " " + msg, thr);
      this.setCode(code);
   }

}
```

Simple custom exception

```
public class MyException extends AbstractException{
 static{
   // populate internal map with module-specific errors
   init("module1.errors.properties", MyException.class);
 }     

public MyException(String code){
 super(getMessageByCode());
}
// rest code omited

}
```

Simple usage of custom exception in code:

```
throw new MyException("ERROR_404");
```

Propblems what I can see in this code:

1. ERRORS map exists for all child classes of abstract exception
2. Concurrent access to static ERRORS field.

Question is, how to avoid these problems, may be someone have a better solution of my problem?

Comment: Are you wanting to share error messages between modules?

Comment: What sort of problem when concurrent access to static ERRORS? there is no dirty read/write for those static members, isn't it?

Comment: Maybe you should use `java.util.logging` instead.  Do you really need to keep those errors in memory?

Comment: 2Brian No, I don't want. With common parent class I just want to have incapsulate same logic populating and using errors map.

Comment: [Hashtable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40471/java-hashmap-vs-hashtable) is synchronized while HashMap is not.

Answer (score 1):

This design won't work because there will be only one copy of `ERRORS`, shared among all subclasses.  One possible solution is an ExceptionFactory that manages the various `ERRORS` maps and can create and exceptions of the required subclasses for you.  For example

```
public static class AbstractException extends RuntimeException 
{ 
    String code;
    String message;
    public void setCode(String code) { this.code = code; }
    public void setMessage(String message) { this.message = message; }
}

public static class MyException1 extends AbstractException{ }

public static class MyException2 extends AbstractException{ }

public static class ExceptionFactory
{
    private Map<Class<?>,Map<String,String>> errorMaps = new HashMap<Class<?>, Map<String,String>>();
    public void register(Class<? extends AbstractException> exType, String fileName)
    {
        Map<String,String> errors = new HashMap<String,String>();
        // load errors from fileName
        errorMaps.put(exType, errors);
    }

    public <T extends AbstractException> T newException(Class<T> exType, String code)
    {
        Map<String,String> map = errorMaps.get(exType);
        String message = map.get(code);
        T ex;
        try
        {
            ex = exType.newInstance();
            ex.setCode(code);
            ex.setMessage(message);
            return ex;
        }
        catch(InstantiationException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(IllegalAccessException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```