# Safest option to replace hashtable?

Tags: java, hashtable, replace

I have some old 3rd party Java code I am converting to Java 6. It contains `HashTable` instances, which are flagged as obsolete collections. What should I replace them with? What is the safest option?

Comment: Just leave them. Obsolete doesn't mean the same as not supported.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although not marked as deprecated in the API doc, `HashTable` is obsolete, you could consider use [`HashMap`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html).

For the differences, you could check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40471/java-hashmap-vs-hashtable).

The main differences (the two that the doc said) are:

1. `HashMap` is unsynchronized;
2. `HashMap` can contain `null`s.

So beware of these two when you swap in `HashMap` for `HashTable`.

Answer (score 4):

`java.util.HashMap` has very similar semantics, however it is not synchronized. If you depend on the synchronized behavior, you can use `java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap`