# Why does Hashtable not take null key?

Tags: java, collections

Why does Hashtable not take a `null` key?

Also why does HashMap allow `null` keys?

What is the purpose of making these two classes Key behaviour so different?

Comment: Well, this might answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40471/java-hashmap-vs-hashtable

Comment: If you look into `AbstractMap` you will see here and there that NULL keys are specially handled. You can use null keys in `Hashtable` if you wrap them into objects (`NullKey`) and treat them specially.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

From the `Hashtable` [JavaDoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html):

```
To successfully store and retrieve objects from a hashtable, the objects used 
as keys must implement the hashCode method and the equals method.
```

In a nutshell, since `null` isn't an object, you can't call `.equals()` or `.hashCode()` on it, so the `Hashtable` can't compute a hash to use it as a key.

[`HashMap`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) is newer, and has more advanced capabilities, which are basically just an improvement on the `Hashtable` functionality. As such, when `HashMap` was created, it was specifically designed to handle `null` values as keys and handles them as a special case.

Specifically, the use of `null` as a key is handled like this when issuing a `.get(key)`:

```
(key==null ? k==null : key.equals(k))
```

Comment: HashMap is not a wrapper around HashTable. It is a separate implementation.

Comment: @EJP - I didn't say that it actually _was_ a wrapper around `Hashtable`, but rather that it wrapped the same _functionality_, since it does what `Hashtable` does and more.

Comment: So when you said 'wrap' you didn't mean 'wrap'. Possibly you mean 'implement' or 'provide'.

Comment: @EJP - Yes, you're correct. "wrap" was a bad word to use. I've updated my answer to better reflect what I meant, as well as reality.

Comment: to put it in a nutshell "the hashcode for key is calculated using key's hashcode(key classes hashcode) in hashtable and hashmap's hashcode in hashmap"

Answer (score 5):

It is just an implementation detail.

`Hashtable` is the older class, and its use is generally discouraged. Perhaps they saw the need for a null key, and more importantly - null values, and added it in the `HashMap` implementation.

Comment: I'm not sure I would call the handling of `null` values in a class's external interface an implementation detail, but I agree that it was likely a design oversight for `HashTable` that was corrected in `HashMap`.

Comment: The `Map` interface says nothing of `null` values, so each implementation can choose :)

Comment: Concurrent hashmap is a newer class & still it doesn't allows null key

Answer (score 5):

Hashtable predates the collections framework, and was part of JDK 1.0. At that time null keys were probably considered not useful or not essential, and were thus forbidden. You might see it as a design error, just as the choice of the name `Hashtable` rather than `HashTable`.

Then, several years later, came the collections framework, and Hashtable was slightly modified to fit into the framework. But the behavior on null keys was not changed to keep backward compatibility.

Hashtable should be deprecated, IMHO.

Answer (score 3):

I will let you know how the hashmap stores the objects internally:

HashMap stores the values through put(key,value) and gets the values thorugh `get(key)`. The process follows the concept of Hashing.

When we say `put(key,value)` - Internally `hashCode()` for the key is calculated and being taken as the input for `hashfunction()` to find the bucket location for storing.

In case of Collision - while calculating the `hashcode()` there may be a possibility the key is different but the `hashcode()` is same, at that time after finding out the bucket location the storing is done in the linked list. Please Note - While storing as the Map.Entry both the key-value is stored.

When Retrieve of the value through key is done then if during the collision where the key's hashcode() may be same then the value is retrived though `equals()` function to find out the desired key's value.

Regards,
Anand

Answer (score 1):

Apart from all the details given in other answers, this is how hashmap allow NULL Keys. If you look at the method `putForNullKey()` in Hashmap (JDK 5) , it reserves the index "0" for the null key. All values for the null key are kept inside the "0" index of the array.

There is nothing special about storing NULL value as all the put and lookup operations work based on the Key object.

In hashtable, Java does not have these mechanisms and hence hashtable does not support NULL key or values.

Answer (score 0):

They're two separate classes for two different things. Also, HashTable is synchronized. HashTable also came before HashMap, so naturally it would be less advanced. It probably didn't make sense to generate a null hashcode in early Java.