# Regarding collection framework

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, hashtable, hashset

I have some questions about Java `Collection` objects...

1. When we add objects to a collection like `HashSet` or `HashMap`, how the the objects internally stored?
2. Why doesn't `Hashtable` allow `null` values?

Comment: Duplicate of your second question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7556357/why-does-hashtable-not-take-null-key

Answer (score 6):

You're not adding an *object* to the collection. You're adding a *reference*.

As for why `HashTable` doesn't allow `null` keys and values - it's just a design decision; in some cases it's helpful to disallow null keys, while in others it's annoying. `HashMap` *does* allow for both null keys and values, for example. There are various reasons for prohibiting nulls:

- Usually a null key *or* a null value indicates a programming error in the calling code. Rejecting this at the point of insertion makes it far easier to find the error than waiting until the code fetches a value and *then* has an unexpected null.
- If you *know* that values in a map can't be null, then you don't need to do a separate check for containment and then fetch: you can fetch, and if the result is null, you know the key was missing.
- It takes a bit more work to handle null keys in the map implementation. While null values can *sometimes* be useful, null keys almost *never* are.

Comment: Just to be clear, a popular reason for disallowing null keys or values is because they frequently represent a logic error in the program that's using them.  For example, Guava did a study on Google's code base that suggested that 95% of collections never have nulls (and rejecting nulls helps those users debug), and 5% of collections need nulls (and there's usually a workaround for that case).

Comment: Would it be fair to say that null key is singular, since only one reference may be mapped to null at any given time?

Comment: Eh?  You can have as many references to `null` as you like.  Of course, all nulls are equal and everything...

Comment: @LouisWasserman if a map supports null, it will be capable of supplying at most one different result for `map.get(null)` until the next call of `map.put(null,value)`. Hence my statement that there is only one reference (value) mapped to null (key) at any given time.

Comment: @corsiKa: Sure - although I'm not sure how helpful that is. Any particular reason for mentioning it?

Comment: @JonSkeet Perhaps it's just me, but `HashMap does allow for both null keys and values` seems to imply that the relationship of the map to null values (which a map that supports them can hold many) is the same as the relationship of the map to the null key.

Comment: Eh?  I'm...not sure what you're saying there.  Certainly a map can have at most one null key and arbitrarily many null values.

Answer (score 0):

Hashtable does not allow null values because it uses the equals and hashcode methods of the objects added to it

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function