# Java Collections HashTable and HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap, hashtable

Why in **Java** one null key is allowed in **Hashmap**, while in case of **Hashtable** it is not allowed ?

Comment: The question is a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11981852/why-hashtable-does-not-allows-null-keys-or-values)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does Hashtable not take null key?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7556357/why-does-hashtable-not-take-null-key)

Comment: Hashtable is older where as HashMap is newer as it was added in 1998. When they implemented HashMap they wanted to lift some of the limitations of Hashtable.

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

If you look at docs of `HashMap`

> The `HashMap` class is roughly equivalent to `HashTable`, except that it is unsynchronized and permits `null`'s.)

`HashTable` is the older version of `HashMap` which failed in that case of handling `null`'s. And `HashMap` got that feature added into it to get more advanced than `HashTable`.

Answer (score 0):

Hash table is very old class , from JDK 1.0

To understand this, first of all you need to understand comments written on this class by author.

> This class implements a hashtable, which maps keys to values. Any non-null object can be used as a key or as a value. To successfully store and retrieve objects from a hashtable, the objects used as keys must implement the hashCode method and the equals method.

`HashTable` class is implemented on hashing mechanism, that’s mean to store any key-value pair, its required hash code of key object. If key would be null, it will not able to given hash ,it will through null pointer exception and similar case for value it is throwing null if the value is null.

But later on it was realized that null key and value has its own importance that is why one null key and multiple null values are allowed in later implemented classes like `HashMap` class.

For  hash map null  keys will allow and there is a null check is there for keys if the key is null then that element will be stored in a zero location in Entry array. null key we can  use for some default value..

Answer (score 0):

HashMap allows the null key. If you try to insert the another value of same key, it will override it.

Incase of HashTable,  put(K key, V value) throws the Null pointer Exception if the key or value is null.

Refer the source code.
HashMap: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/HashMap.java#HashMap.put%28java.lang.Object%2Cjava.lang.Object%29

HashTable: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Hashtable.java#Hashtable.put%28java.lang.Object%2Cjava.lang.Object%29