# Does Java have a data structure that stores key value pairs, equivalent to IDictionary in C#?

Tags: java, data-structures, dictionary

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What will store a Key-Value list in Java or an alternate of C# IDictionary in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8061598/what-will-store-a-key-value-list-in-java-or-an-alternate-of-c-sharp-idictionary)

In C# there is a data structure named [IDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s4ys34ea.aspx) which stores a collection of key-value pairs.  Is there simillar data structure in Java?  If so, what is it called and can anybody give me an example of how to use it?

Comment: Its Key-Value not string-value

Answer (score 22, accepted):

One of the best ways is HashMap:

Use this sample:

```
HashMap<String, Integer> dicCodeToIndex;
dicCodeToIndex = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

// valuating
dicCodeToIndex.put("123", 1);
dicCodeToIndex.put("456", 2);

// retrieving
int index = dicCodeToIndex.get("123");
// index is 1
```

Look at this link: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

Comment: Any class that implements java.util.Map will do, not just HashMap.

Comment: I would say that creating a new TreeMap or LinkedHashMap is just as simple.  And if I rewrite your code properly to use the Map as the reference type on the left hand side I can change the implementation at will.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the various implementations of java.util.Map (see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html). The most commonly used Map implementation for a dictionary-like map should be HashMap.

However, depending on the exact usage scenario, another type of map might be better.

Comment: an example would be nice tho