# difference between hashmap and hashtable|

Tags: java, hashmap, hashtable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Differences between HashMap and Hashtable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40471/differences-between-hashmap-and-hashtable)

I went to an interview the other day interviewer asked me under which situation will there be a problem to use hashmap rather then hashtable?
Meaning give a eg where hashtmap use will result in problem but using hashtable will resolve the problem.

He told me that the machine in which the code is run is single core!!

I gave a eg

```
Time        Thread1            Thread 2
   t0    tb.put("a",1)       
   t1     tb.put("a",2)          int a = tb.get("a");
```

I told that if at t1 if both t1 and t2 executes simultaniously then it will result in problem.
He said that since it is a single core cpu it will never execute 2 statements in parallel

Can someone please clarify that , when will there be a problem?
Any example of situation?

EDIT:I posted the question by interchaing hashmap and hashtable.I know that hashtable method are synchronized and that of hashmap are not and i had told it to him

To experient i implemted following.And the code never crashed? I dint use hashtable but still it  t is a hashmap in A :)

```
public class MyT extends Thread {

    HashMap<String,String > a = A.t;
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            a.put("a", "one");
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyT t1 = new MyT();
        t1.start();
        MyT t2 = new MyT();
        t2.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Mr. Pointy-Hair probably thinks that tb.put/tb.get contains only one cpu instruction :)

Answer (score 3):

I think you have to do the following things first before asking:

1. Search on stackoverflow
2. Search on Google

The following results are obtained by above two methods:

[StackOverflow: Differences between HashMap and Hashtable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40471/851432)

**Google**

[what is the difference between HashMap and Hashtable](http://www.allinterview.com/showanswers/20263.html)

[Difference between HashMap and HashTable? Can we make hashmap synchronized?](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2010/10/difference-between-hashmap-and.html)

Hope that helps :)

Comment: @Jaomos:I know that methods of hashtable are synch and that of map are not.Give a me example where it will fail.Dont act too smart.Am also a java programmer and am not a new baby

Answer (score 2):

Unlike the new collection implementations, `Hashtable` is synchronized. That's why I could imagine a situation when using `HashMap` would create a problem, and using `Hashtable` would resolve it.

The fact that it's single core is of no consequence: if `Thread1` is pre-empted in the middle of a `put` call, `Thread2` will see an inconsistent state, and may crash.

Comment: An interview is a two-way process. If you say something right, and he says it's wrong (in a topic he chose, no less), that says something about him. If this is someone you'd be working with, it may be a warning flag.

Answer (score 0):

Well, just because it's single core, doesn't mean you can't have race conditions. It possibly (probably?) means you won't have memory visibility issues, but you can certainly run multiple threads on a single core, and they can still be scheduled such that you get race conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good link, you can refer to that: [Differences between HashMap and Hashtable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40471/differences-between-hashmap-and-hashtable)

I am wondering whether they ask you exactly as you said, because it seems that he want to ask which is thread-safe and which is not.

`Hashtable` is thread-safe, but why he ask problem with `Hashtable`?

Answer (score 0):

Here syncoronization is the main reason why hash table should be used in this scenario. Even though a single core is used in this case, you cannot gaurantee that the `tb.put("a",2)` will complete its execution before `tb.get("a")` gets called.

This can cause inconsistancies in the output. If HashTable is used, Since it is syncronised, `put` is completed before `get` is called.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40471/differences-between-hashmap-and-hashtable) thread for more details