# JTextPane HTML Image integration

Tags: java, html, swing, image, jtextpane

I have a JTextPane and I do it :

```
HTMLEditorKit kit = new HTMLEditorKit();
HTMLDocument doc = new HTMLDocument();`

this.setEditorKit(kit);
this.setDocument(doc);
```

Then I do :

```
profilePictureSrc = "http://ola/profilePicture1.jpg";
chatContent ="<img src=\"" + profilePictureSrc + "\">";
```

Where profilePictureSrc is a URL Object.

It works but I must use a String instead of the URL ([Java Hashtable put method slow down my application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8426139/java-hashtable-put-method-slow-down-my-application))

How Can I do that ? Do I have to put the picture files somewhere and use a relative Path to reach them ? Thank you very much for your ideas

Best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert url objects to strings.

String urlstring = myurl.toString();