# Advantages of HashTable

Tags: java, collections

What is the main advantage of using `Hashtable` comparing with `HashMap`. Because, `Hashtable` main advantage is synchronization.
Now map can also synchronized using `synchronizedMap()`.

```
Map m = Collections.synchronizedMap(hashMap);
```

Comment: IINM, use of HashTable is actually discouraged and you should try to always use HashMap in any new code. Hashtable is retained for compatibility with old code.

Comment: Why then java not deprecate that HashTable?

Comment: There is no such thing HashTabl, it is called Hashtable and it is "prehistoric" (before) the Collection IFS. Its methods are synchronized, however it does not guarantee that the references to the objects that populate the Hashtable cannot be modified concurrently.

Comment: I think main difference is hashtables is "does not allow nulls" compare with HashMap.

Comment: What is the advantage of restricting nulls on HashTable?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Differences between HashMap and Hashtable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40471/differences-between-hashmap-and-hashtable)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Hashtable` existed before the collections framework, so it is retained mainly for backward compatibility. Use `ConcurrentHashMap` instead.

Note that there is a slight semantic difference - `Hashtable` does not allow nulls, while `HashMap` allows null values and a null key.

Comment: Performance wise, What is the differnce between synchronizedMap() and Hashtable?

Comment: There shouldn't be a difference. But ConcurrentHashMap is better

Answer (score 2):

`HashTable` has been deprecated a long time ago. The main difference is that `HashTable` is synchronized internally, while `HashMap` is not. This is however seen as a disadvantage, because using the `HashTable` on a single thread incurs the penalty of locking and unlocking when it is not needed.

Also, another point that renders `HashTable`'s synchronization not so useful is the fact that executing two thread-safe operations in a sequence does not guarantee atomicity of the entire sequence, think for example to:

```
if(key does not exist)
    add key
```

while both testing existence and adding are thread-safe, the above construct is not, because another thread might interrupt it in the middle. Therefore, external synchronization is needed anyway.

As such, I see no reason to use `HashTable` at all these days...