# java.util.Properties Vs java.util.Map<String, String>

Tags: java, properties, hashmap

Just wanted to know. What are the differences between `java.util.Properties` Vs `java.util.HashMap<String, String>`? Which is preferable?

Comment: Dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40471/differences-between-hashmap-and-hashtable

Answer (score 16, accepted):

They are similar, but from a design perspective, the [`Properties`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) class is considered to be one of the "mistakes" of java, because it *is* a [`Hashtable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html) (rather than *using* a Hashtable). It should have been an interface.

Always use the abstract where possible, so this is preferred:

```
Map<String, String> stuff = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

Tend to avoid using `Properties` unless you *have* to.

Answer (score 28):

There are different purpose of these two utility class. Map, or in your case, HashMap is general purpose storage object where you have unique key, and values to which they point. HashMap can have any object type as their key and any object type as their values.

java.util.Properties is, however, a special purpose map. It is developed to read/write from/to properties files. It has special methods to do so [see `load(..)`]. Map does not.

So, you have different situations to use them. Places where you need properties to read, you better go with Properties. And places where you want to have lookup values stored off some logic, you go with `HashMap<String, String>`.

There is no hard and fast rule, you can use `HashMap<String, String>` and `Properties` interchangeably. But as an engineer, use *right tool for the task*.

Answer (score 5):

Propeties extends Hashtable, which is synchronized by default.  HashMap is not synchronized by default.  You're trading built-in thread safety for a slight performance improvement, one that you're likely to be unable to measure.

Properties is an older class from Java 1.0.  HashMap is part of Joshua Bloch's newer collections API.

Answer (score 3):

You have the modern-day `ConcurrentHashMap<String, String>` for thread safety. Don't really use `Properties` unless you are using it to read a `.properties` file.

Answer (score 1):

The Properties class is an extension of Hashtable, basically adding functionality to write + read from a disk in a set format (text value pairs like this):

```
key1=value1
key2=value2
```

If you want to store it to disk and use that format then use a Properties, otherwise use a HashMap or Hashtable.

Answer (score 0):

`java.util.Properties` is a `Hashtable<Object,Object>` therefore you can see it as a synchronized  form of `java.util.HashMap<String, String>`

Properties is nice to handle... properties : ) If you use it for other purposes, then your choice will depend on the concurrency management in your program