# When should I use a Hashtable versus a HashMap

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, hashtable

<s>This is not a question about the differences between `Hashtable` and `HashMap`.</s> I understand that a `Hashtable` object cannot accept `null` values for either key or value entries, that it is synchronized collection, and that it uses slightly less memory than a `HashMap`.

I'm wondering about the scenarios where it would be more appropriate to use a `Hashtable` instead of a `HashMap`.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40471/differences-between-hashmap-and-hashtable

Comment: @MattWolfe It's not a duplicate of that question. That question goes over the differences. I know the differences. I'm asking about when it is appropriate to use one over the other.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

> This is not a question about the differences between `Hashtable` and `HashMap`

Well it is really...

> I'm wondering about the scenarios where it would be more appropriate to use a `Hashtable` instead of a `HashMap`.

Precisely when you *want* the differences between the two:

- When you want to run on Java 1.1
- When you want each operation to be synchronized (getting you a *form* of thread safety, so long as you never iterate over it) - and for some reason don't want to use `Collections.synchronizedMap` over a `HashMap`
- When you don't want to be able to store null values
- When the memory difference is actually significant (only after you've *proved* this is the case) - I wasn't even aware of this difference, personally...
- When you're forced to by a nasty API which returns or takes `Hashtable` (relatively rare, fortunately)

I can't remember the last time I was in that situation, personally - I would say it's vanishingly rare to be appropriate to use `Hashtable` in modern Java code.

Comment: Just to add from java 1.6 onwards you will get HashTable as obsolete collection.

Comment: @thinksteep: Really? I don't see any deprecation notices on the 1.6 docs: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html

Comment: @JonSkeet I only put that bit about memory just to cover all the bases - in practice the memory difference is quite small as to be negligible. I was wondering if there were any strange corner cases where a `Hashtable` would be more useful than a `HashMap`. Thanks for enumerating all the different scenarios!

Comment: It seems my netbeans misleading.

Comment: @VivinPaliath: Have added a generalization of skaffman's answer as well.

Comment: +1: Hashtable grows slower so it can have slightly less unused capacity, but at the cost of CPU (as it may need to grow more times) HashMap has to double each time as it has to be a size of a power of 2.

Comment: @VivinPaliath You need to use a `Hashtable` when you have a API which requires it, in every other case you can use `HashMap` or `Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap())`

Comment: I'm not sure I'd agree with point 2 (When you want each operation to be synchronized). In that case I'd still use HashMap (or ConcurrentHashMap) - I would only use Hashtable if I had no choice.

Answer (score 19):

Never.

[`Hashtable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Hashtable.html) was the original implementation of a map in Java 1. It's been overtaken by the [`Map<K,V>`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html) implementations defined in the [*Java Collections Framework*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_collections_framework). Sure, `Hashtable` has been retrofitted to implement `Map` but that's not terribly useful.

It has the main problem in that it's synchronized. This means that it will be slow in any circumstance where it is shared between threads. [`ConcurrentHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) is a better choice in that situation. If you are running on a single thread then the un-synchronized [`HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HashMap.html) is a better choice.

Answer (score 8):

## With `InitialContext` in JNDI

I can think of only one valid reason - when you're using an API that requires it, such as [JNDI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Naming_and_Directory_Interface)’s hugely irritating  [`InitialContext`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.naming/javax/naming/InitialContext.html) class.

Other than that, I can see no good reason to use [`Hashtable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Hashtable.html) at all. You can get a synchronized version of [`HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HashMap.html) by using `Collections.synchronizedMap`, or use a [`ConcurrentMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap.html) implementation such as [`ConcurrentHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) or [`ConcurrentSkipListMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListMap.html)

Answer (score 3):

I only see Hashtables in legacy apps/ libraries.

If you can, use ConcurrentHashMap or Collections.synchronizedMap if you need a synchronized Map.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedMap%28java.util.Map%29

Answer (score 1):

Knowing when to use one class or structure over another is essentially understanding the differences between the two, and deciding which one best suits the problem at hand based on those differences.

> I understand that a Hashtable object cannot accept null values

So in the situation where you need to store null values, a `Hashtable` would not be appropriate.

Also, in a `Hashtable`, enumeration is not fail-safe. So if you need to be able to change the content of the structure while enumerating, a `Hashtable` would be more appropriate.