# Adding element to HashTable of Stack objects

Tags: java, stack, hashtable

I have a `HashTable` of `Stack` objects:

```
Hashtable<String, Stack<Integer>> ht;
```

I want the data structure to be something like this:

```
"foo" => [3,6,12]
"bar" => [5,8,1]
```

`"foo"` and `"bar"` are keys and the two `[x,y,z]`s are the stacks.

How do I do something like push an `Integer` onto the stack in the hash table with key `"a"`?

Many thanks.

Comment: ht.get("a").push(myInteger), but it would had been better if you had tried this by yourself in your code

Comment: hmm.. maybe I should close.. this was too obvious to benefit others?!  Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this :

```
if(ht.containsKey("a")) {
  ht.get("a").push(0); // push some Integer
}
else {
  Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<Integer>();
  stack.push(0); // push some integer
  ht.put("a",stack);
}
```

You need to use [push()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html#push(E)) of [Stack](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html).

**P.S:** Move to [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) instead of `HashTable` if you can.

Read [When should I use a Hashtable versus a HashMap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9536077/when-should-i-use-a-hashtable-versus-a-hashmap)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried

```
yourHashTable.get("a").push(new Integer(2));
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to modify a given stack, retrieve a reference to it and and add the new integer.

```
myHashTable.get("a").push(new Integer(7));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Stack<Integer> stack = hashtable.get(key);
stack.push(myint);
hashtable.put(key, stack);
```

Something like this, maybe :)?