# How can I set Hashtable value to be array?

Tags: java, data-structures, hashtable

Is it possible to create in Java a `Hashtable` where key is integer and values is an array of integer. I tried below code, and it doesn't work. Does anyone know how to make such data-structure?

```
int[] a = {0, 0, 0};
// does not work!!!!
Hashtable<int, int[]> entry = new Hashtable<NodeT, a>;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several things:

1) Please don't use `Hashtable`, instead use `HashMap`. `Hashtable` is the old, synchronized version and people don't use it anymore.

Please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9536077/when-should-i-use-a-hashtable-versus-a-hashmap)  excellent answer when to use `Hashtable`.

2) Please code against an interface unless you have good reason not to (so your `entry` should be of type `Map` instead). This allows you to change the underlying implementation to a different kind of map easily.

3) Please read the [official Java tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html) it explains how to use the map interface and basically it should be more or less like this:

`Map<Integer, int[]> entry = new HashMap<>();`

Or if you are using Java older than 7 `Map<Integer, int[]> entry = new HashMap<Integer, int[]>();` since [the diamond operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/type-inference-generic-instance-creation.html) was introduced in Java7. Also notice that on both sides you need the same values inside `<>`. Why would you write `<NodeT, a>` on the right hand side? I gather `a` was a try to initialize it with `a` but I don't understand the `NodeT`.

You have to use `Integer` instead of `int` as generics in Java do not accept primitive types. `int[]` works fine since this is an object in Java.

After that you need to put your entries into the map.

Answer (score 2):

1. Don't use `Hashtable`. Use [`HashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html). `HashMap` is more performant and `Hashtable` has been basically deprecated since Java 2.
2. You can't use `int` as a key, it has to be an `Object`, which in this case is the [autoboxed](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) [`Integer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html), so use:

   ```
   Map<Integer, int[]> = new HashMap<>();
   ```