# how to iterate and compare over Hashtable<String, Map<String, Set<String>>> in java

Tags: java, dictionary, hashtable

I have a structure like below ,

```
Key: active-csr-HA-profile & Value: {sapd-outside=[outside], sapd-extra4=[extra4], sapd-extra3=[extra3], sapd-inside=[inside]}
Key = sapd-outside, Value = [outside]
Key = sapd-extra4, Value = [extra4]
Key = sapd-extra3, Value = [extra3]
Key = sapd-inside, Value = [inside]
Key: standby-csr-HA-profile & Value: {sapd-outside=[outside], sapd-extra4=[extra4], sapd-extra3=[extra3], sapd-inside=[inside]}
Key = sapd-outside, Value = [outside]
Key = sapd-extra4, Value = [extra4]
Key = sapd-extra3, Value = [extra3]
Key = sapd-inside, Value = [inside]
```

the above if of format `Hashtable<String,  Map<String, Set<String>>>`

I want to compare if sapd-outside of active-csr-HA-profile is same as one of the keys of standby-csr-HA-profile. So compare each key of active-csr-HA-profile to each key of standby-csr-HA-profile.

I looked some similar questions but what i am working out is not solving the purpose.

Comment: That  doesn't make sense. Hashtable is a legacy interface you shouldn't be using in the first place. Why not a `Map<String, Map....>`?

Comment: Beyond that: when you have "not working" code, then provide a [mcve]. Also *link* to the questions you read before. We have no idea what research you did, and what helped you , and what not.

Comment: @GhostCat `Hashtable` is not an interface; it is an implementation of the `Map` interface and tries to address concurrency affairs. But indeed, modern code should, but only when synchronization is desired, use `Collections.synchronizedMap` rather than the `Hashtable` class. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9536077/when-should-i-use-a-hashtable-versus-a-hashmap).

Comment: "interface" as in "something to program with", not in the class vs interface sense ;-) Beyond that, Hashtable exists since Java 1.0 ... and yes, it later became a map, but a hashtable of maps is just ... wrong.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned in the comments, the [`Hashtable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html) is considered obsolete. Its replacement is [`HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html). If you wish make `HashMap` synchronized the same way the `Hashtable` does, use the [`Collections::synchronizedMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedMap-java.util.Map-) decorator on it.

The structure of your `Hashtable` looks a bit unclear. I guess the following structure matches your one the best and I base my solution on it.

```
Hashtable<String,  Map<String, Set<String>>> map = new Hashtable<>();

Map<String, Set<String>> activeCsrHAProfile = new HashMap<>();
activeCsrHAProfile.put("sapd-outside", new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("outside")));
activeCsrHAProfile.put("sapd-extra4", new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("extra4")));
activeCsrHAProfile.put("sapd-extra3", new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("extra3")));
activeCsrHAProfile.put("sapd-inside", new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("inside")));

Map<String, Set<String>> standbyCsrHAProfile = new HashMap<>();
standbyCsrHAProfile.put("sapd-outside", new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("outside")));
standbyCsrHAProfile.put("sapd-extra4", new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("extra4")));
standbyCsrHAProfile.put("sapd-extra3", new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("extra3")));
standbyCsrHAProfile.put("sapd-inside", new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("inside")));

map.put("active-csr-HA-profile", activeCsrHAProfile);
map.put("standby-csr-HA-profile", standbyCsrHAProfile);
```

In case my structure differs a bit from yours, there would be no problem to amend the solution in order to match your structure - the principle is the same.

```
Set<String> sapdOutsideOfActiveCsrHAProfile = map.get("active-csr-HA-profile")
                                                 .get("sapd-outside");

map.get("standby-csr-HA-profile").entrySet()
   .stream()
   .filter(i -> i.getValue().containsAll(sapdOutsideOfActiveCsrHAProfile))
   .forEach(e -> System.out.println("Found at: " + 
       "key=" + e.getKey() + ", value=" + e.getValue()));
```

- `.filter(i -> i.getValue().containsAll(..)` filters those entris which values `Set<String>` contains all of the required Strings.
- `.forEach(..)` gives a consumer performing an action over all the matching results.

In case you need the `boolean` representing whether the match has occurred or not, do:

```
boolean matches = map.get(..).entrySet().stream().filter(..).findFirst().isPresent();
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, `HashTable` is a debatable choice. Regardless of the implementation you choose, you could create your own class to manage the messy stuff:

```
public class CustomMap extends Hashtable<String, Map<String, Set<String>>> {

    public CustomMap() {
        super();
    }

    public boolean compareEntries(String key1, String key2) {
        if (!this.containsKey(key1) || !this.containsKey(key2) || this.get(key1).size() != this.get(key2).size())
            return false;

        for (String innerKey : this.get(key1).keySet()) {
            if (!this.get(key2).containsKey(innerKey)) {
                return false;
            }

            final Set<String> setA = this.get(key1).get(innerKey);
            final Set<String> setB = this.get(key2).get(innerKey);
            if (!setA.containsAll(setB) || !setB.containsAll(setA)) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

I took the assumption there could be more entries in your table and you'd want to compare specific entries.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through a map with its entry set:

```
    Hashtable<String,  Map<String, Set<String>>> table = new Hashtable();

    for (Map.Entry<String, Map<String, Set<String>>> entry : table.entrySet()) {
        String key = entry.getKey();
        Map<String, Set<String>> map = entry.getValue();

        for (Map.Entry<String, Set<String>> mapEntry : map.entrySet()) {
            String mapKey = mapEntry.getKey();
            Set<String> set = mapEntry.getValue();

            for (String text : set) {
                // ...
            }
        }           
    }
```

Nesting sets inside maps inside maps makes the code hard to read though, you might want to use specialized objects instead.

As others have said, in most cases HashMap is preferrable compared to an Hashtable.