# Using HashMap in multithreaded environment

Tags: java, multithreading

I was going through an interview question [on JavaRevisited](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2011/04/top-20-core-java-interview-questions.html) and I'm having difficulty understanding this question :

> What’s wrong with using a HashMap in a multithreaded environment? When get() method go into an infinite loop?

In my opinion, it's not a problem to use `HashMap` inside a multi-threaded environment, as long as our application is not accessing/reading threads which are modifying the created `HashMap`, rather than simply accessing the HashMap.

So, as I see it, there's not a problem as long as in the application we are just accessing the `HashMap` in a multi-threaded environment.

Please let me know if my understanding is correct.

Comment: I think you have a typo in your question.  "as our application is creating threads which are modifying the created HashMap, rather than modifying the HashMap".  I suspect the first "modifying" should be "accessing" or "reading".

Comment: Yes , thanks for pointing it out , our APplication doesn't create Threads explicitly . we just access the Data inside the HashMap .

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> What’s wrong using HashMap in multithreaded environment? When get() method go to infinite loop?

It is a bug to have multiple threads use a non-synchronized collection (really any mutable class) in an unprotected manner.  Certain if *each* thread had their own `HashMap` *instance* then this is not an issue.  It is a problem if multiple threads are adding to the *same* `HashMap` instance without it being `synchronized`.  Even if just 1 thread is modifying a `HashMap` and other threads are reading from that same map without synchronization, you will run into problems.

If you need to use the same hash table object in multiple threads then you should consider using `ConcurrentHashMap`, wrapping each of the accesses to the `HashMap` in a `synchronized {}` block, or making use of the `Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<...>())` construct.

Chances are that the `get()` goes to an infinite loop because one of the threads has only a *partially updated* view of the `HashMap` in memory and there must be some sort of object reference loop.  That's the peril of using an unsynchronized collection with multiple threads.

> So in my understanding, it's not a problem as long as in the application we are just accessing the HashMap in a multi-threaded environment?

If by "accessing" you mean "reading", then this is true **with qualifications**.  You must make sure:

- All of the updates to the `HashMap` are completed *before* the threads are instantiated and the thread that creates the map also forks the threads
- The threads are only using the `HashMap` in read-only mode – either `get()` or iteration without remove
- There are no threads updating the map

If any of these conditions are not true then you will need to use a synchronized map instead.

Comment: I also have similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41952171/modifying-hash-map-from-a-single-thread-and-reading-from-multiple-threads) where I am using HashMap in multithreaded environment but I  figured out I can use ConcurrentHashMap but it looks like there might be a thread safety issue in my code. I wanted to see what is the best way by which I can fix those in my code?

Answer (score 3):

This is a classical question. ArrayList and HashMap are not synchronized, while Vector and HashTable are. You should therefore use HashTable unless you are very careful defining mutexes yourself.

In other words, the methods in e.g. HashTable will ensure that no other thread is working with the HashTable at any given time. If you use a HashMap, you'd have to do that manually by ensuring that you synchronize on HashMap before you call the method.

Update: checkout @Gray's comment. It looks like wrapping HashMap with Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap()) is the way to go now.

EDIT: other posters have answered way better than I did. My answer, however, generated an interesting discussion on the use of the soon to be deprecated Vector, Stack, Hashtable and Dictionary classes, so I'm leaving the question here, as a head to the comments below. Thanks guys!

Comment: `HashTable` is all but deprecated and should not be used.  If you need a concurrent HashMap then you should use ConcurrentHashMap or `Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap())`.

Comment: @Gray Oh, that's interesting, I had no idea. Do you have a reference to that? With HashTable not being marked as deprecated, this came as a surprise. Thanks!

Comment: @Gray And since we are at it, is vector also deprecated?

Comment: @Gary Or use ConcurrentHashMap which can be safely iterated without a CME.

Comment: @Miquel Vector, Stack, Hashtable and Dictionary were replaced in Java 1.2 about 13 years ago. You should only use these when you have to. Interestingly an alternative to Properties was never provided even though you can `properties.put(1, 0.0)` which is unsafe. ;)

Comment: Yes, use of Vector is also frowned upon, yes.

Comment: @PeterLawrey and Gray, thanks, that's good to know! Seriously though, I don't want to miss on the next one. Where do you pick up on such things being all but deprecated, if not on the javadoc? thx!

Comment: They are "deprecated" since the introduction of the `Concurrent` package, which introduces thread-safe collections with a finer granularity than `Vector` or `HashTable` (which achieve thread-safety through a kind of `big-lock` on the whole data structure).

Comment: Here's a good discussion on the subject.  The 2nd answer (with the higher score) is a good read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40471/differences-between-hashmap-and-hashtable

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks a lot! I changed my original answer instead or removing it because I really value your comments on this.

Answer (score 3):

We know that `HashMap` is a non-synchronized collection whereas its synchronized counter-part is `HashTable`. So, when you are accessing the collection in a multithreaded environment and all threads are accessing a single instance of collection, then it's safer to use `HashTable` for various obvious reasons e.g. to avoid dirty reads and to maintain data consistency. In the worst case, this multithreaded environment can result in an infinite loop as well.

Yes, it is true. `HashMap.get()` can cause an infinite loop. Let us see how??

If you look at the source code `HashMap.get(Object key)` method, it looks like this:

```
 public Object get(Object key) {
    Object k = maskNull(key);
    int hash = hash(k);
    int i = indexFor(hash, table.length);
    Entry e = table[i];
    while (true) {
        if (e == null)
            return e;
        if (e.hash == hash &amp;&amp; eq(k, e.key))
            return e.value;
        e = e.next;
    }
}
```

> `while(true){...}` can always be a victim of an infinite loop at runtime in a
>   multithreaded environment, IF, somehow e.next can point to itself. This will result in an infinite loop. But, how e.next will point to itself?

This can happen in `void transfer(Entry[] newTable)` method, which is invoked at the time the HashMap resizing is done.

```
    do {
        Entry next = e.next;
        int i = indexFor(e.hash, newCapacity);
        e.next = newTable[i];
    newTable[i] = e;
        e
= next;
} while (e != null);
```

This piece of code is prone to produce the above condition if resizing happens and at the same time, other threads tried to modify the map instance.

The only way to avoid this scenario is to use synchronization in code, or better, use the synchronized collection.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that they meant to access to a shared copy of `HashMap`. `Shared mutable state`.

Since it is not `synchronized` every thread will grab its copy from the main memory, modify, and overwrite it.

```
HashMap with one entry <n, 1>

thread 1 grab the copy

thread 2 grab the copy

thread 1 modify <n, 2>

thread 2 modify <n, 3>

thread 1 is done, and stores the copy in the main memory

now memory is <n, 2>

thread 2 is done and stores the copy

now memory is <n, 3>

The state thread 1 is lost
```