# can we use Hashmap in multithreaded environment?

Tags: java, multithreading

Hashmap is not synchronized. Suppose I want to use Hashmap in multithreaded environemnt. what will be the behaviour of hashmap?

Comment: Its behavior will be undefined...

Comment: My car doesn't have a brakes. What will happen if I drive it at 100 KMPH?.

Comment: The behavour will be of a HashMap. The Map does'nt know how it is accessed (synchronized or not). It depends all on the **use case**.

Comment: There is a blog article out there explaining in great detail what happened to someone who used it. The result was deadlock with the expected hanging threads. Can't find the link anymore though. In short: use Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<>());

Comment: That depends on how you use the `HashMap`, the implementation of `HashMap` you are using, the types of objects it contains, the type of computer and operating system, and random factors. It is possible to write thread-safe code that uses data structures that are not themselves thread-safe. Your question lacks the detail to be answerable.

Comment: Possible duolicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11050539/using-hashmap-in-multithreaded-environment

Answer (score 4):

Since it is not synchronized, it's not thread safe.

Use [ConcurrentHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html), if you are looking for a synchronization .

Comment: +1 I am agree with you.

Comment: -1: use Collections.synchronizedMap() (not actually a -1 but I don't entirely agree)

Comment: I found that always misleading: of course methods are sync and there are some special ones (putIfAbsent). But if you are doing multiple operations (in a block) in diferent threads {get(); remove(); put();} you propably still need to sync externally. It is not always substitute HashMap by ConcurrentHashMap and you are done.

Comment: @nablex Why I have to write extra line of code?? Designers already wrote code for me :). Best part is it works without any bugs.

Comment: @PeterMmm I follow your point but it depends on the usage (see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/510632/whats-the-difference-between-concurrenthashmap-and-collections-synchronizedmap).

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ Using the static method prevents you from having a dependency on the specific implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Concurrent modification will cause unpredicted in `HashMap` out put and you will experience with `ConcurrentModificationException`  .

> Note that this implementation is not synchronized. If multiple threads
>   access a hash map concurrently, and at least one of the threads
>   modifies the map structurally, it must be synchronized externally. (A
>   structural modification is any operation that adds or deletes one or
>   more mappings; merely changing the value associated with a key that an
>   instance already contains is not a structural modification.)

[Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)