# Modifying hash map from a single thread and reading from multiple threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, atomic

I have a class in which I am populating a map `liveSocketsByDatacenter` from a single background thread every 30 seconds and then I have a method `getNextSocket` which will be called by multiple reader threads to get a live socket available which uses the same map to get this info.

```
public class SocketManager {
  private static final Random random = new Random();
  private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
  private final Map<Datacenters, List<SocketHolder>> liveSocketsByDatacenter = new HashMap<>();
  private final ZContext ctx = new ZContext();

  // Lazy Loaded Singleton Pattern
  private static class Holder {
    private static final SocketManager instance = new SocketManager();
  }

  public static SocketManager getInstance() {
    return Holder.instance;
  }

  private SocketManager() {
    connectToZMQSockets();
    scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        updateLiveSockets();
      }
    }, 30, 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }

  private void connectToZMQSockets() {
    Map<Datacenters, ImmutableList<String>> socketsByDatacenter = Utils.SERVERS;
    for (Map.Entry<Datacenters, ImmutableList<String>> entry : socketsByDatacenter.entrySet()) {
      List<SocketHolder> addedColoSockets = connect(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue(), ZMQ.PUSH);
      liveSocketsByDatacenter.put(entry.getKey(), addedColoSockets);
    }
  }

  private List<SocketHolder> connect(Datacenters colo, List<String> addresses, int socketType) {
    List<SocketHolder> socketList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String address : addresses) {
      try {
        Socket client = ctx.createSocket(socketType);
        // Set random identity to make tracing easier
        String identity = String.format("%04X-%04X", random.nextInt(), random.nextInt());
        client.setIdentity(identity.getBytes(ZMQ.CHARSET));
        client.setTCPKeepAlive(1);
        client.setSendTimeOut(7);
        client.setLinger(0);
        client.connect(address);

        SocketHolder zmq = new SocketHolder(client, ctx, address, true);
        socketList.add(zmq);
      } catch (Exception ex) {
        // log error
      }
    }
    return socketList;
  }

  // this method will be called by multiple threads to get the next live socket
  public Optional<SocketHolder> getNextSocket() {
    Optional<SocketHolder> liveSocket = Optional.absent();
    List<Datacenters> dcs = Datacenters.getOrderedDatacenters();
    for (Datacenters dc : dcs) {
      liveSocket = getLiveSocket(liveSocketsByDatacenter.get(dc));
      if (liveSocket.isPresent()) {
        break;
      }
    }
    return liveSocket;
  }

  private Optional<SocketHolder> getLiveSocket(final List<SocketHolder> listOfEndPoints) {
    if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(listOfEndPoints)) {
      Collections.shuffle(listOfEndPoints);
      for (SocketHolder obj : listOfEndPoints) {
        if (obj.isLive()) {
          return Optional.of(obj);
        }
      }
    }
    return Optional.absent();
  }

  private void updateLiveSockets() {
    Map<Datacenters, ImmutableList<String>> socketsByDatacenter = Utils.SERVERS;

    for (Entry<Datacenters, ImmutableList<String>> entry : socketsByDatacenter.entrySet()) {
      List<SocketHolder> liveSockets = liveSocketsByDatacenter.get(entry.getKey());
      List<SocketHolder> liveUpdatedSockets = new ArrayList<>();
      for (SocketHolder liveSocket : liveSockets) {
        Socket socket = liveSocket.getSocket();
        String endpoint = liveSocket.getEndpoint();
        Map<byte[], byte[]> holder = populateMap();

        boolean status = SendToSocket.getInstance().execute(3, holder, socket);
        boolean isLive = (status) ? true : false;
        SocketHolder zmq = new SocketHolder(socket, liveSocket.getContext(), endpoint, isLive);
        liveUpdatedSockets.add(zmq);
      }
      liveSocketsByDatacenter.put(entry.getKey(), liveUpdatedSockets);
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see in my above class:

- From a single background thread which runs every 30 seconds, I populate `liveSocketsByDatacenter` map with all the live sockets.
- And then from multiple threads, I call `getNextSocket` method to give me live socket available which uses `liveSocketsByDatacenter` map to get the required information.

Is my above code thread safe and all the reader threads will see `liveSocketsByDatacenter` accurately? Since I am modifying `liveSocketsByDatacenter` map every 30 seconds from a single background thread and then from a lot of reader threads, I am calling `getNextSocket` method so I am not sure if I did anything wrong here.

It looks like there might be a thread safety issue in my "getLiveSocket" method as every read gets a shared `ArrayList` out of the map and shuffles it? And there might be few more places as well which I might have missed. What is the best way to fix these thread safety issues in my code?

If there is any better way to rewrite this, then I am open for that as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be thread-safe, your code must synchronize any access to all shared mutable state.

Here you share `liveSocketsByDatacenter`, an instance of `HashMap` a **non thread-safe** implementation of a `Map` that can potentially be concurrently read (by `updateLiveSockets` and `getNextSocket`) and modified (by `connectToZMQSockets` and `updateLiveSockets`) without synchronizing any access which is already enough to make your code non thread safe. Moreover, the values of this `Map` are instances of `ArrayList` a **non thread-safe** implementation of a `List` that can also potentially be concurrently read (by `getNextSocket` and `updateLiveSockets`) and modified (by `getLiveSocket` more precisely by `Collections.shuffle`).

The simple way to fix your 2 thread safety issues could be to:

1. use a `ConcurrentHashMap` instead of a `HashMap` for your variable `liveSocketsByDatacenter` as it is a natively thread safe implementation of a `Map`.
2. put the **unmodifiable** version of your `ArrayList` instances as value of your map using [`Collections.unmodifiableList(List<? extends T> list)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList-java.util.List-), your lists would then be immutable so thread safe.

For example:

```
liveSocketsByDatacenter.put(
    entry.getKey(), Collections.unmodifiableList(liveUpdatedSockets)
);`
```

3. rewrite your method `getLiveSocket` to avoid calling `Collections.shuffle` directly on your list, you could for example shuffle only the list of live sockets instead of all sockets or use a copy of your list (with for example `new ArrayList<>(listOfEndPoints)`) instead of the list itself.

For example:

```
private Optional<SocketHolder> getLiveSocket(final List<SocketHolder> listOfEndPoints) {
    if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(listOfEndPoints)) {
        // The list of live sockets
        List<SocketHolder> liveOnly = new ArrayList<>(listOfEndPoints.size());
        for (SocketHolder obj : listOfEndPoints) {
            if (obj.isLive()) {
                liveOnly.add(obj);
            }
        }
        if (!liveOnly.isEmpty()) {
            // The list is not empty so we shuffle it an return the first element
            Collections.shuffle(liveOnly);
            return Optional.of(liveOnly.get(0));
        }
    }
    return Optional.absent();
}
```

---

For #1 as you seem to frequently read and rarely (only once every 30 seconds) modify your map, you could consider to rebuild your map then share its immutable version (using [`Collections.unmodifiableMap(Map<? extends K,? extends V> m)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableMap-java.util.Map-)) every 30 seconds, this approach is very efficient in mostly read scenario as you no longer pay the price of any synchronization mechanism to access to the content of your map.

Your code would then be:

```
// Your variable is no more final, it is now volatile to ensure that all 
// threads will see the same thing at all time by getting it from
// the main memory instead of the CPU cache
private volatile Map<Datacenters, List<SocketHolder>> liveSocketsByDatacenter 
    = Collections.unmodifiableMap(new HashMap<>());

private void connectToZMQSockets() {
    Map<Datacenters, ImmutableList<String>> socketsByDatacenter = Utils.SERVERS;
    // The map in which I put all the live sockets
    Map<Datacenters, List<SocketHolder>> liveSockets = new HashMap<>();
    for (Map.Entry<Datacenters, ImmutableList<String>> entry : 
        socketsByDatacenter.entrySet()) {

        List<SocketHolder> addedColoSockets = connect(
            entry.getKey(), entry.getValue(), ZMQ.PUSH
        );
        liveSockets.put(entry.getKey(), Collections.unmodifiableList(addedColoSockets));
    }
    // Set the new content of my map as an unmodifiable map
    this.liveSocketsByDatacenter = Collections.unmodifiableMap(liveSockets);
}

public Optional<SocketHolder> getNextSocket() {
    // For the sake of consistency make sure to use the same map instance
    // in the whole implementation of my method by getting my entries
    // from the local variable instead of the member variable
    Map<Datacenters, List<SocketHolder>> liveSocketsByDatacenter = 
        this.liveSocketsByDatacenter;
    ...
}
...
// Added the modifier synchronized to prevent concurrent modification
// it is needed because to build the new map we first need to get the
// old one so both must be done atomically to prevent concistency issues
private synchronized void updateLiveSockets() {
    // Initialize my new map with the current map content
    Map<Datacenters, List<SocketHolder>> liveSocketsByDatacenter = 
        new HashMap<>(this.liveSocketsByDatacenter);
    Map<Datacenters, ImmutableList<String>> socketsByDatacenter = Utils.SERVERS;
    // The map in which I put all the live sockets
    Map<Datacenters, List<SocketHolder>> liveSockets = new HashMap<>();
    for (Entry<Datacenters, ImmutableList<String>> entry : socketsByDatacenter.entrySet()) {
        ...
        liveSockets.put(entry.getKey(), Collections.unmodifiableList(liveUpdatedSockets));
    }
    // Set the new content of my map as an unmodifiable map
    this.liveSocketsByDatacenter = Collections.unmodifiableMap(liveSocketsByDatacenter);
}
```

Your field `liveSocketsByDatacenter` could also be of type `AtomicReference<Map<Datacenters, List<SocketHolder>>>` , it would then be `final`, your map will still be stored in a `volatile` variable but within the class `AtomicReference`.

The previous code would then be:

```
private final AtomicReference<Map<Datacenters, List<SocketHolder>>> liveSocketsByDatacenter 
    = new AtomicReference<>(Collections.unmodifiableMap(new HashMap<>()));

...

private void connectToZMQSockets() {
    ...
    // Update the map content
    this.liveSocketsByDatacenter.set(Collections.unmodifiableMap(liveSockets));
}

public Optional<SocketHolder> getNextSocket() {
    // For the sake of consistency make sure to use the same map instance
    // in the whole implementation of my method by getting my entries
    // from the local variable instead of the member variable
    Map<Datacenters, List<SocketHolder>> liveSocketsByDatacenter = 
        this.liveSocketsByDatacenter.get();
    ...
}

// Added the modifier synchronized to prevent concurrent modification
// it is needed because to build the new map we first need to get the
// old one so both must be done atomically to prevent concistency issues
private synchronized void updateLiveSockets() {
    // Initialize my new map with the current map content
    Map<Datacenters, List<SocketHolder>> liveSocketsByDatacenter = 
        new HashMap<>(this.liveSocketsByDatacenter.get());
    ...
    // Update the map content
    this.liveSocketsByDatacenter.set(Collections.unmodifiableMap(liveSocketsByDatacenter));
}
```

Comment: Great suggestion. I understood everything. I have decided to use `AtomicReference` so that we can get rid of synchronized blocks as you mentioned. I have put up a gist [here](https://gist.github.com/TechGeeky/ae9f3b8863710a67c1d68a21c74c24da) just to make sure I got everything right basis on your suggestion. Now since we are using `AtomicReference`, at many places I need to use `get()` method on `AtomicReference` to get the actual Map back. I have edited those as well in my gist. Let me know I got everything right.

Comment: @user5447339 sounds good except point #3 that don't seem to be covered

Comment: oops yeah I missed that somehow.. Just edited the gist again.. Can you explain why we don't need synchronized blocks if map is volatile? Also the benefit of not using `ConcurrentHashMap` is because we will get performance benefit if we use `HashMap` here with immutable version? Just for my understanding, can you explain why this will be more beneficial?

Comment: @user5447339 1. You simply don't need synchronized block to safely access to a volatile variable, it could only be needed if you wanted to read and modify it atomically which is not the case here. 2. An HashMap is lock free, a ConcurrentHashMap is not so using an `HashMap` avoid the overhead of a locking mechanism

Comment: @user5447339 I forgot to mention also that you need to keep the reference of your map in a local variable and use this variable instead of the member variable for consistency, check my response update

Comment: Got it. Regarding storing reference of a map in a local variable in the `updateLiveSockets()` method, this line will stay same as it is `this.liveSocketsByDatacenter.set(Collections.unmodifiableMap(liveSockets));` right? And set will always happen only on member variable? Only part will change is during the iteration of this map that we should use same instance of local variable?

Comment: @user5447339 1. yes 2. yes 3. exactly

Comment: Is there any benefit of doing this? I mean using local variable everywhere but not using member variable in this context?

Comment: @user5447339 it is to prevent bugs due to an inconsistency issue, indeed image that while iterating over the map referred by `liveSocketsByDatacenter`, `liveSocketsByDatacenter` is set to another map reference, you could then end up with a bug because an entry has been removed such that `liveSocketsByDatacenter.get(dc)` would return null while a non null value is expected

Comment: Hi Nicolas, I saw an update in your answer which I missed earlier. You modified `updateLiveSockets()` method by adding `synchronized` keyword and I saw one more change where you initialize new  map with current map  content and then we use same new map to set on the AtomicReference object since I got slightly confused on this so I have edited my [gist](https://gist.github.com/TechGeeky/ae9f3b8863710a67c1d68a21c74c24da) again. Just wanted to make sure I have got everything right. It looks like from your last edit, I might have messed up `updateLiveSockets()` method.

Comment: Actually I lately realized that in updateLiveSockets you directly modify liveSocketsByDatacenter, you don't rebuild it from an empty map that's why need to prevent concurrent calls by adding synchronized and we start from a map initialized with the current map. About your gist you don't need both liveSocketsByDatacenter and updatedLiveSocketsByDatacenter only liveSocketsByDatacenter

Comment: aahh I see got it.. I updated my gist again with the changes you suggested. Can you take a look and let me know this time I got it right?

Answer (score 1):

It seems, that you can safely use `ConcurrentHashMap` here instead of regular `HashMap` and it should work.

In your current approach, using regular HashMap, you need to have synchronization of methods:

`getNextSocket`, `connectToZMQSockets` and `updateLiveSockets` (everywhere you update or read the HashMap) like a `sychronized` word before those methods or other lock on a monitor common for all these methods - And this is not because of `ConcurrentModificationException`, but because without synchornization reading threads can see not updated values.

There is also problem with concurrent modification in the getLiveSocket, one of the simplest way to avoid this problem is to copy the listOfEndpoints to a new list before shuffle, like this:

```
private Optional<SocketHolder> getLiveSocket(final List<SocketHolder> endPoints) {
    List<SocketHolder> listOfEndPoints = new ArrayList<SocketHolder>(endPoints);
    if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(listOfEndPoints)) {

      Collections.shuffle(listOfEndPoints);
      for (SocketHolder obj : listOfEndPoints) {
        if (obj.isLive()) {
          return Optional.of(obj);
        }
      }
    }
    return Optional.absent();
  }
```

Comment: Using `synchronized` everywhere is the least elegant solution.

Comment: @user5447339 Looks to be. I don't see any obvious race conditions or other problems.

Comment: @Kayaman looks like there is a thread safety issue in my "getLiveSocket" method, every read gets a shared ArrayList out of the map and shuffles it in. And there might be few others. Any thoughts how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

As you can read in detail e.g. [here](http://crunchify.com/hashmap-vs-concurrenthashmap-vs-synchronizedmap-how-a-hashmap-can-be-synchronized-in-java/), if multiple threads access a hash map concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies the map structurally, it must be synchronized externally to avoid an inconsistent view of the contents.
So to be thread safe you should use either Java Collections synchronizedMap() method or a ConcurrentHashMap.

```
//synchronizedMap
private final Map<Datacenters, List<SocketHolder>> liveSocketsByDatacenter = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<Datacenters, List<SocketHolder>>());
```

or

```
//ConcurrentHashMap
private final Map<Datacenters, List<SocketHolder>> liveSocketsByDatacenter = new ConcurrentHashMap<Datacenters, List<SocketHolder>>();
```

As you have very highly concurrent application modifying and reading key value in different threads, you should also have a look at the Producer-Consumer principle, e.g. [here](http://crunchify.com/java-producer-consumer-example-handle-concurrent-read-write/).

Comment: looks like there is a thread safety issue in my "getLiveSocket" method, every read gets a shared ArrayList out of the map and shuffles it in. And there might be few others. Any thoughts how can I fix it?

Answer (score -1):

Using ConcurrentHashMap should make your code threadsafe. Alternatively use synchronized methods to access existing hashmap.