# Is there a way to store multiple data types in a single hashtable variable?

Tags: java

I have a `Hashtable` which has a key of `String` and the value as `String`, but I've reached a point in my project where I need to be able to store multiple different data types. For example, I'm going to need to store `int`, `String`, `Date`, etc, all in one `Hashtable`.

Comment: Isn't it good option to create a object with get/set and add that object HashTable/ArrayList (or) what ever the collection you are interested? If you add multiple data types, while retrieving if you don't know exact index and datatype, you will end up with classcastexception.

Comment: This sounds like a very fragile data structure. Could you describe what it is you're trying to achieve generally, so maybe someone can suggest a way to better structure your data?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`HashTable` or any Collection `Map` can handle this, except for `int` and other primitive types: you can't store primitive types, only `Object` references. `int` will need to be wrapped as a `Integer` object.

Comment: So then will I be able to retrieve it as the data type which it was stored as?

Comment: Not really, no -- not without a cast, and it'll still be finicky.  You'd be _much_ better off using different maps for different types, or -- better yet -- just creating a class with fields with each of the different names, instead of having a `Map` where you sort of hope you make sure everything's of the right type.

Answer (score 6):

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>()
```

This gives you a map with keys of type String and values of type Object, which basically means any descendant of type Object (Date, Integer, String etc.). Other answers correctly point to the fact that instead of using primitives such as int, boolean it is required to use their counterparts Integer, Boolean etc.

The return type of `get` operation on such map is `Object`. Thus, it is developer's responsibility to handle type information correctly.

A good answer to the question as to what is the difference between Hashtable and HashMap is provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40471/differences-between-hashmap-and-hashtable).

Answer (score 4):

You can have it store the general data type `Object`, though that will not allow primitive data types.

Answer (score 4):

While this is possible, it's generally not a good idea. More often than not this leads to type casting exceptions and problems.

The HashTable can be set to store generic Objects as opposed to specific class types, however the type conversion when retrieving them does not happen automatically.

In order to get the object back out of the collection, some form of type checking routines will have to be developed.

You're better off creating a separate collection for each class type you want to store.

PS: I would also recommend using a HashMap instead of HashTable. HashTable has been deprecated.

Comment: Thanks I didn't not know that.

Answer (score 0):

Change your HashTable to `Hashtable<String, Object>` and when you want to store an `int` you need to cast it first(or use autocast) to an `Integer`. After getting your value from the table you can determ your type by `if(value instanceof String)` and so on for any type.

Comment: There is no need to typecast -- autoboxing will do it automatically (Java 5+).

Comment: The class is called Hashtable and it takes two type parameters, not one.