# Java create list has more field

Tags: java, list

At first sory for my bad english :)

I want create new list `(Arraylist, hashmap etc.. which is appropriate)` this list have 6 field for example;

```
ArrayList<Integer, Integer, String, Integer, String, Integer> nData = new ArrayList<>();
```

**this is not correct i know** but i need list has `<int, int, String, int, String, int>`
but how? thank you

Comment: You should read this, it will help you get more answers (not that you really need them in this case) [how to accept an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: Oh. My. God. It's the first time when I'm seen such application of generics :)

Answer (score 5):

Create a `Class` which wraps all those fields, and add instances of this class to the `ArrayList`.

For example:

```
public MyClass {
  private Integer field1;
  private Integer field2;
  private String field3;
  private Integer field4;
  private String field5;
  private Integer field6;

  // constructor

  // getters/setters
}
```

And then:

```
List<MyClass> nData = new ArrayList<MyClass>();
MyClass instance = new MyClass(1, 2, "String1", 4, "String2", 5);
nData.add(instance);
```

Comment: +1 I would use `int` instead of `Integer` and make fields `final` where possible.

Answer (score 1):

I think best suggestion depends on details & constraints of your design, but it seems like order of data types is constant. Thus, `HashMap<int,Object[]>` or    `Hashtable<int,Object[]>` may be useful for your purpose.  You can see differences between HashMap and HashTable [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40471/differences-between-hashmap-and-hashtable).

Answer (score 0):

Create a new class that has the fields you want and make an ArrayList of that class.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class which has all these field, say MyClass, like this:-

```
class MyClass
{
  Integer a;
  Integer b;
  String c;
  Integer d;
  String e;
  Integer f;
}
```

After that create `ArrayList` like this:-

```
ArrayList<MyClass> nData = new ArrayList<MyClass>();
```

You can add the values in your list as:-

```
MyClass m = new MyClass(1,2,"abcd",3,"bcde",4);
nData.add(m);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. create class with holds those fields, or
2. use Integer instead int, and create List and then just cast it to required type

   ```
   List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
   for (Object o : list)
   {
   if (o instanceof Integer)
   System.out.println( "" + ((Integer) o).intValue() + " is integer");
   else 
   System.out.println( "" + ((String) o) + " is String");
   }
   ```