# ConcurrentHashMap and Hashtable in Java

Tags: java, hashmap, hashtable

What is the difference between a ConcurrentHashMap and a Hashtable in Java?

Which is more efficient for threaded applications?

Comment: For a non-threaded application, use `HashMap`.

Comment: It is always recommended to use concurrenthashmap over hashtable. Please find the article on it http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp07233/index.html

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/a/40878/632951 for more info.

Comment: @Keith Randall, There is no non-threaded application in java. Its either multithreaded or single threaded (only main thread). You are talking about single threaded application.

Answer (score 126, accepted):

`ConcurrentHashMap` uses multiple buckets to store data. This avoids read locks and greatly improves performance over a `HashTable`. Both are thread safe, but there are obvious performance wins with `ConcurrentHashMap`.

When you read from a `ConcurrentHashMap` using `get()`, there are no locks, contrary to the `HashTable` for which all operations are simply synchronized.
`HashTable` was released in old versions of Java whereas `ConcurrentHashMap` is a java 5+ thing.

`HashMap` is the best thing to use in a single threaded application.

Comment: There's also `ConcurrentHashMap.putIfAbsent()` that doesn't have an equivalent in the old `Hashtable`. And when you only read from a `ConcurrentHashMap`, there are no locks, contrary to the `Hashtable` for which all operations are simply synchronized.

Comment: @FrankPavageau added your very useful comments in the Original answer.

Answer (score 177):

> ConcurrentHashMap and Hashtable locking mechanism

- `Hashtable` is belongs to the Collection framework; `ConcurrentHashMap` belongs to the Executor framework.
- `Hashtable` uses **single lock** for whole data. `ConcurrentHashMap` uses **multiple locks** on segment level (16 by default) instead of object level i.e. whole `Map`.
- `ConcurrentHashMap` locking is applied only for updates. In case of retrievals, it allows full concurrency, retrievals reflect the results of the most recently completed update operations. So reads can happen very fast while writes are done with a lock.
- `ConcurrentHashMap` doesn't throw a `ConcurrentModificationException` if one thread tries to modify it while another is iterating over it and does not allow null values.
- `ConcurrentHashMap` returns `Iterator`, which fails-safe (i.e. iterator will make a copy of the internal data structure) on concurrent modification.
- `ConcurrentHashMap` uses a database shards logic (`Segment<K, V>[] segments`) is known as **Concurrency-Level**, i.e. divides the data into shards(segments) then puts locks on each shard (segment) instead of putting a single lock for whole data (`Map`). The default value is 16.

To understand the ConcurrentHashMap more technically please look at this [link](http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/05/27/best-practices-for-using-concurrenthashmap/)

**The following analogy helps you get understand the concept only(not logic)**

- Assume `Hashtable` and `ConcurrentHashMap` are two types of Homes.
- `Hashtable` locks home's main door.
- `ConcurrentHashMap` locks specific room door instead of main door.

> Which is more efficient for threaded applications?

`ConcurrentHashMap` is more efficient for threaded applications.

Comment: Home example won over all the theory :)

Comment: Does this mean ConcurrentHashMap is better than HashTable? In what case HashTable is better than the other one?

Comment: @Tiina there is never a case when Hashtable is the preferred class.  If your process needs to be thread-safe, use ConcurrentHashMap.  If not, use java.util.HashMap.