# locking mechanism used in concurrentHashMap and hashtable

Tags: java

This question was recently asked to me in java interview.
I tried to search it later but couldn't find the exact answer.
In case if any1 have a link o the answer please let me know.
So here goes my question :

ConcurrentHashMap and Hashtable are synchronized.
But which locking mechanism it uses during write operation while locking.

Comment: It is explained in the Javadoc class comment of these classes.

Comment: Hope it will help :
[concurrenthashmap and hashtable][1]
 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12646404/concurrenthashmap-and-hashtable-in-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The great thing about open source is you can just look up [the source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.java)!  [This bit](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.java#ConcurrentHashMap.Segment) is particularly relevant.

The concurrency in ConcurrentHashMap is quite intricate - it breaks the contents up into `Segment`s to avoid locking the whole table, and uses `volatile` fields to allow lock-free concurrent reads.

Answer (score 1):

ConcurrentHashMap uses internally divides buckets into segments and one particular segment can be locked by a thread for writing purpose.

Segment is nothing but a static class which is specialized version of hash tables and implements Reentrantlock to simplify locking as

```
static class Segment<K,V> extends ReentrantLock implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 2249069246763182397L;
        final float loadFactor;
        Segment(float lf) { this.loadFactor = lf; }
}
```

Segments's constructor calls ReentrantLock's no arg constructor and creates a non fair lock.

Answer (score 0):

Two main features of  ConcurrentHashMap is:

- While writing on  ConcurrentHashMap, locks only a part of the map
- Reads can generally happened without locking.

its possible to have two parallel threads writing to the **ConcurrentHashMap** at the same time. As per the default implementation of ConcurrentHashMap, atmost 16 threads can write & read in parallel. But the worst case is, if the two objects lie in the same segment or partition of **ConcurrentHashMap**, then parallel write would not be possible.

Comment: But internally to lock the segments which locking technique is used ?