# Difference between Hashtable and ConcurrentHashMap

Tags: java, collections

Can someone  elaborate this line briefly?

> “In Summary ConcurrentHashMap only locked certain portion of Map while
>   Hashtable lock full map while doing iteration”

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12646404/18157

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is scalability.  ConcurrentHashMap divides the map in parts and locks them individually.  So multiple threads can access those different parts simultaneously.  But a given segment is synchronized.

In essence it's about partial locking of the collection versus full locking.

Read [this](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2011/04/difference-between-concurrenthashmap.html) for more.