# Data structure for writing a dictionary in java

Tags: java

Which data structure would be more preferable for making a dictionary in Java ? What would be better a tree or a hash-table ?

Comment: And "dictionary" means ..? In any case, consider a Prefix Trie or Heap for immutable (read: file-based) "word list dictionary"; if just looking for a Map, see the answer ..

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40471/differences-between-hashmap-and-hashtable

Comment: offline dictionary in java where you enter a word in a text field and the meaning of that word.

Comment: @user1753035 I would consider using a "database" (it doesn't have to be relational) for this; and let that do the lifting. Then the file is pre-created and consumed through said "database" API. E.g. see BerkelyDB (or equivalent, has benefit of simplicity) or SQLite (has benefit of tools) etc. Of course this would also be a fun exercise in creating a disk-based Heap (or B-tree or Extendible Hash). The advantage of using a "database" or disk-based approach is to avoid having to load everything into memory; with the right disk layout it's just a few trivial seeks to look up the definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use something like

```
Map<String,Integer> dictionary = Collections.synchronizedMap(new TreeMap<String,Integer>());
```

Instead of Integer as the value of a String key, you can use a Class object which probably can hold a list that contains all the positions of that word inside the document
There are methods for easy retrieval of key values from the `TreeMap`. Following is the way you get an iterator out of `TreeMap.`

```
Set<Entry<String,Integer>> set = dictionary.entrySet();

Iterator<Entry<String,Integer>> entryItr = set.iterator();

Entry<String,Integer> entry = null;

while(entryItr.hasnext()){
entry = entryItr.next();
// Do whatever you want.
}
```

Answer (score 5):

A Map. Nothing else. If you want sorting, use a TreeMap. Otherwise: HashMap.

A Dictionary *maps* a (key-)word to it's description or translation.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a Trie, especially for memory efficiency and also prefix lookups.
I have an implementation that implements the map interface under APL on github: https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-utils/tree/c7b1fa586590d121d9f44c1686cb58de0349eb0b/blaze-common-utils

Check it out and maybe it fits your needs better than a simple map.

Answer (score 0):

According to the lecture in Introduction to Algorithms of MIT, I would say it is better to go with hash-tables. Because you can do operations in O(1) instead of O(logn)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0M_kIqhwbFo