# How is Hashtable different to Hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap, hashtable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Differences between HashMap and Hashtable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40471/differences-between-hashmap-and-hashtable)

I've seen hash tables and hash maps used in different code but they look like they do the same thing. Is there a difference between them? Which one should I use in my code?

Comment: Yep, the primary difference is that Hashtable is synchronized, and HashMap is not.  They also have different superclass hierarchies.  (FWIW, I've on a couple of occasions seen fairly severe failures in large commercial apps due to using HashMap in a concurrent environment.)

Comment: BTW, it's "HashMap" and "Hashtable".  Note the capitalization.

Comment: Did you consider reading the Javadoc?

Comment: @HotLicks - *"I've on a couple of occasions seen fairly severe failures in large commercial apps due to using HashMap in a concurrent environment."* - but using a `Hashtable` might be a bad idea too due to contention issues.  Concurrent applications require more sophisticated thinking ... if you want them to scale.

Comment: `Hashtable` is more or less deprecated; `ConcurrentHashMap` is designed to work in a concurrent environment, but is much better at it.

Comment: @StephenC -- In these cases there was very little contention ... had there been contention the bugs would have been found in testing rather than in the field.  And when a HashMap is updated concurrently the results aren't pretty.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**java.util.Hashtable** methods are **synchronized** , **java.util.Hashmap** methods are not. If you use **Hashtable** there will be a **performance hit** as no **two threads** will be able to access its methods at the same time.
If you care about **Thread safety** in your app **Hashtable** is the way to go. if you dont care about thread safety **Hashmap** is the way to go as it is mor eefficient then **hashtable.**
also java.util.Hashtable doesnt allow any null keys, where as java.util.HashMap allows one null key.

Answer (score 4):

Hashtable is synchronized, where as HashMap is not. This means if you only have a single thread accessing the data, use a HashMap, otherwise use a Hashtable.

Comment: its Hashtable , note the `t`:)

Comment: @GanGnaMStYleOverFlowErroR wow, never noticed, haha =)

Answer (score 1):

HashTable dont't allow null keys where as hashmap allows one null key