# NullPointerException when putting a non-null key and value into a Hashtable

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, hashtable

java.util.Hashtable's null pointer exception is occuring in the following code when neither of the arguments to put() are null :

```
import java.util.Hashtable;

interface action
{
   void method();
}

class forclass implements action
{
  public void method()
  {
    System.out.println("for(...){");
  }
}

class ifclass implements action
{
  public void method()
  {
    System.out.println("if(..){");
  }
}

public class trial
{
  static Hashtable<String,action> callfunc;
  //a hashtable variable
  public static void init()
  {
    //System.out.println("for"==null); //false
    //System.out.println(new forclass() == null); //false
    callfunc.put("for",new forclass()); //exception occuring here
    callfunc.put("if",new ifclass());
    //putting values into the hashtable
  }
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    init(); //to put stuff into hashtable
    action a = callfunc.get("for");
    //getting values for specified key in hashtable
    a.method();
    callfunc.get("if").method();
  }
}
```

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException - 

  at trial.init(trial.java:33)

  at trial.main(trial.java:38)

why is this exception occuring? how do i fix it?

Comment: Don't use Hashtable unless you have to, do use Java Code Convension such as TitleCase for class names.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have not initialized your `Hashtable`: -

```
static Hashtable<String,action> callfunc; // Reference points to null
```

> when neither of the arguments to put() are null

You should rather use `HashMap`, which allows `1 null key`, to avoid getting `NPE` when using `put` with `null key`, method which in case of `Hashtable` throws `NPE`, because it does not allow `null keys, or value`.

**So, change your declaration to: -**

```
static Hashtable<String,action> callfunc = new Hashtable<String, action>();
```

or even better: -

```
static Map<String, action> callfunc = new HashMap<String, action>();
```

---

As a side note, you should follow `Java Naming Convention` in your code. All the class name and interface name, should start with `UpperCase` letter, and follow `CamelCasing` thereafter.

Comment: oops silly mistake thanks fixed it, also according to the docs                       public Object put(Object key, Object value) does throw the
NullPointerException - if the key or value is null, so i was checking that and overlooked the error that you pointed out

Comment: @ShruthiB.S.. Ah! forgot that you are using `Hashtable` which does not allow null keys. You should rather use `HashMap`, which allows `1 null` key.

Answer (score 1):

`callfunc` reference is null not the inputs.

Try this:

```
static Hashtable<String,action> callfunc = new Hashtable<String,action>()
```

Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40471/differences-between-hashmap-and-hashtable) post might be useful as to whether you want `Hashtable` or `HashMap`

Comment: correct - sorry I was assuming java's naming convention would kick in here, I'll update post