# Simple parameter-value pairs in Java?

Tags: java

I want to make simple parameter-value pairs of the form (SomeClass, SomeNumber) where the 1st thing is a parameter
and second thing is its value. SomeNumber can be a whole number, fraction, negative number etc. SomeClass can be String, Color or anything that can be paired with "SomeNumber" .

ex of employee and salaries. (John, 19.75), (David, 25.50), (Cathy, 102.50) 
ex for color codes (Color.black, 0), (Color.blue, 2) etc.

Is it a good idea? If not why?
If yes, then how do I do it in Java?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are talking about is [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)

> An object that maps keys to values. A map cannot contain duplicate keys; each key can map to at most one value.

Try [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)

```
Map<String,Double> myMap = new HashMap<String,Double>();
      |       |     
      |       |
SomeClass  SomeNumber

myMap.put("John", 19.75); 

SomeNumber num =  myMap.get("John");
```

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using a `Map` to achieve this type of behavior.  For example for the employees you list:

```
Map<String, Double> employees = new HashMap<String,Double>(); 
employees.put("John", 19.75); 
employees.put("David", 25.50); 
employees.put("Cathy", 102.50);
```

You can then access the elements using the key.

```
double salary = employees.get("John");
```

Comment: An extra question - how do I sort my data on the basis of value?

Answer (score 2):

You can either use a `Map<String, Double>` or you can create a *class* to hold the data. It is up to you to decide which alternative to implement based on the extent of functionality that you're looking for. If you're only looking for a storage mechanism, I would go with the `Map`, but if you want anything more than that (other methods etc.) I would go with the class.

Now, you seem to be merging these distinct 'name' and 'color code' ideas into one single entity. I would refrain from doing that. If you go with the map approach, I would maintain two different maps, one for the (name, salary) pairs and another for the color code data. If you decide to work with classes, I would create two different classes (perhaps both inheriting from the same base-class) to hold each set of data. Don't combine unrelated things into one entity!

---

**Relevant documentation:**

- [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [HashMap or HashTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40471/differences-between-hashmap-and-hashtable).  There is a difference, but you can create a dictionary-like data structure (key-value pairs) using both concepts and Java utilities.

Answer (score 0):

Whether or not this is a good idea depends on what you are going to do with it. One of the easiest ways to do this in Java would be to create a simple object with two fields (and possibly getter and setter methods if you make the variables private), one for the string and one for the decimal value.

```
public class MyClass {
    public String value1;
    public double value2;

    public MyClass(String v1, double v2) {
        value1 = v1;
        value2 = v2;
    }
}
```