# Java object creation compared to C#

Tags: c#, java, android, json, object

I'm creating a mobile app in which I use a webservice written in C# to create JSOn which gets sent to the app written in Java, in C# on the website, I use the following to create a new object:

```
new { success = true }
```

However in Java I can't seem to do the same, what's the best alternative for this in java if I can't do the same?

To put this into context, here is one of my webmethods on the website:

```
[WebMethod]
public object getNode(int intId)
{
    DynamicNode node = new DynamicNode(intId);

    object page = new 
    {
        id = node.Id,
        parentId = node.Parent.Id,
        name = node.Name,
        title = node.GetPropertyValue("title"),
        summary = node.GetPropertyValue("summary"),
        body = node.GetPropertyValue("body"),
        updateDate = node.UpdateDate.ToString(),
        createDate = node.CreateDate.ToString()
    };

    return page;
}
```

If anyone could help me out, I'd be very greatful!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure of the names though so google is useless to me.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html

Comment: You seem to be missing my point entirely. I don't want to create a new instance of an existing object I want to create a new object, for example the data in the object changes too much to abide by a single predefined class.

Comment: In Java, you're better off using a `Map<String, Object>`. You could create an anonymous Object, but you wouldn't be able to access its fields.

Comment: I've read about Hashmap and Hashtable, are these what you refer to?

Comment: Yes, you'll store the name of the field as the key and the object of any type as the value. Either one will work, but [you should know the differences](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40471/differences-between-hashmap-and-hashtable)

Comment: Do you really mean JavaSCRIPT? Or are you looking for the equivalent Java code... because it's almost the same, you just need to call a real constructor instead of the object initializer in your sample code (that's not JSON in your sample, it's a C# object initializer).

http://dotnetbyexample.blogspot.com/2008/01/compacting-c-code-using-implicit.html

Comment: @Jasmine From his clarifications, I think he means an anonymous object, which I don't think is very useful in this case.

Comment: @Jazmine I completely understand its C# but the webservice serialises it into JSON and sends it to my mobile app when requested.

Comment: Knowing the architecture might help - I'm imagining a JAVA app running on Android, with a C# web service in the back end?

Comment: @Sotirios Your answer seems to be what I'm looking for I'll give it a go and try to implement it into the mobile app. Would Google GSON be able to deserialize JSON into a HashMap?

Comment: @Jasmine You're correct about the Java app and C# web service.

Comment: Yes,  it absolutely can.

Comment: @Sotirios Your solution worked, I'd appreciate it if you could post it as an answer so I can mark as correct and sorry for the lack of detail in my original question.

Comment: @LukeAlderton I'm glad you got it working. I don't have all the details of an answer as I still don't quite understand the purpose of what you were doing. You're better off just putting up your own detailed solution. It'll probably be clearer to others since it's exact.

Comment: Okay sounds good to me.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Page{

    int id;
    int parentId;
    String name;
    String title;
    String summary;
    String body;
    String updateDate;
    String createDate;

    public Page(int id, int parentId, String name, String title, String summary, String body, String update Date, String createDate)
    {
        this.id = id,
        this.parentId = parentId;
        this.name = name;
        this.title = title;
        this.summary = summary;
        this.body = body;
        this.updateDate = updateDate;
        this.createDate = createDate;
    }

}

...

Page page = new Page(1, 2, "name", "title", "summary", "body", "updateDate", "createDate");

...
```

Comment: This is what I currently have except I need to be able to add more/less parameters on the fly since the objects i'm going to be sending will be completely different every time.

Comment: If the arguments are completely different each time, then what is the point of an object since nothing else in your code can understand it.  I think you need to explain *what* you are trying to do rather than ask how can I do it.

Comment: It's mostly going to be serialised/deserialized into and from JSON.