# Confusion in the differences between hashmap and hashtable

Tags: c++, data-structures, hashmap, hashtable, binary-search-tree

I have a confusion:

I have read in many posts that **Hash-maps** are implemented as binary search trees which makes the various operations *time complexity of logarithmic order.*

**Hashtables** on the other hand provide *constant time fetching.*

> But, as I read in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40471/differences-between-hashmap-and-hashtable) post, no difference has been provided in terms of the complexity for retrieval/searching of elements in the two data structures.

So, here is my question-

Since hashtables are guaranteed to provide constant searching time complexity, their implementation must differ from those of hash-maps. *So, why will someone ever use hash-maps if they do not provide constant time searching. Also, why in the first place, they are implemented as binary search trees?*

I know hash maps store the keys in sorted form and provide iteration through the map. But, the same could also be provide in the hashtable too.

Comment: Before you retagged it, the question mentioned neither Java nor C++, but used Java terminology throughout and linked to a question that was specifically about Java. It would help avoid confusion if you tagged questions appropriately from the get-go (and ideally used standard terminology for the language you're asking about).

Answer (score 10):

Your confusion stems from the following:

> Hash-maps are implemented as binary search trees

They are not. No sensible naming convention would use the term "hashmap" to describe a structure based on a tree.

For example, in Java, [`HashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) is based on a hash table and [`TreeMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) is based on a tree.

C++ uses neither "hash" nor "tree" in the naming of its standard containers. The two containers that broaly correspond to `HashMap` and `TreeMap` are [`std::unordered_map`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/) and [`std::map`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/).