# ArrayOutOfBoundsException when accessing ArrayList inside ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I have the following problem using an `ArrayList` of `ArrayList`. I do the next:

```
Hashtable<SensorType, ArrayList<Float>> hash = new Hashtable<SensorType, ArrayList<Float>>();

int numKeys = sensors.size();
ArrayList<ArrayList<Float>> arrays = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Float>>(numKeys);  

for(int i = 0; i < arrays.size(); i++){
    ArrayList<Float> aux = new ArrayList<Float>();
    arrays.add(aux);
}

String columns = getColumnsName(sensors);

String sql = "select " + columns + " from " + nameTable + " where " + ID + " BETWEEN " +
    start + " AND " + end + ";"; 

Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sql, null);      
c.moveToFirst();

while(!c.isAfterLast()){

    for(int i = 0; i < numKeys; i++)
        arrays.get(i).add(c.getFloat(i));

    c.moveToNext();
}
```

This always gives me an `ArrayOutOfBoundsException`. It tells that the size of every array (inner) is 0. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Its an arrayList containing an enum belonging to every sensor of a biomedical device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < arrays.size(); i++){
    ArrayList<Float> aux = new ArrayList<Float>();
    arrays.add(aux);
}
```

will not even execute once. Since `arrays.size()` is `0`. So, your `arrays` is empty only. And hence you get that exception.

I guess you need to change your loop to:

```
for(int i = 0; i < numKeys; i++)
```

---

Apart from that, I would do some changes in your code:

- I would declare my list as:

  ```
  List<List<Float>> arrays = new ArrayList<List<Float>(numKeys);
  ```

  Also, be sure you know why you are passing that parameter to `ArrayList` constructor. That is used for setting initial capacity of `ArrayList`. It doesn't fix it's size as in case of `arrays`. You can skip that parameter, if your `ArrayList` is not going to be very large.
- I would use `HashMap` instead of `Hashtable` with `Map` as reference type. [See this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40471/1679863) for reasons.

Comment: `Map` backed by `HashMap`.

Answer (score 2):

When you call `arrays.size()` you will get back `0`. That method returns the number of objects in the `List`. Therefore, your loop never inserts anything.

When you call the `ArrayList` constructor you're using, the `int` is the initial capacity for the list - this is an optimization for when you know in advance how large your `ArrayList` is going to be to prevent unnecessary resizing later when adding items.

Answer (score 0):

```
int numKeys = sensors.size();
ArrayList<ArrayList<Float>> arrays = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Float>>(numKeys);  

for(int i = 0; i < arrays.size()/*<- This returns 0*/; i++){
    ArrayList<Float> aux = new ArrayList<Float>();
    arrays.add(aux);
}
```

**Why arrays.size() returns 0?**

Because if you pass **numKeys** to the constructor of the *ArrayList* it just adjusts the backed array, so it doesn't need to resize the array every time you add a new entry. arrays.size() returns 0 because you never added a new entry, so replace **arrays.size()** with **numKeys**. **The initial size has nothing to do with the actual size of the list.**

**Javadoc:** http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList(int)

**EDIT:** (Not type safe)

You also could replace the arrays ArrayList with a simple array:

```
ArrayList<Float>[] arrays = new ArrayList<Float>[numKeys];
```

Max

Comment: *so it doesn't need to resize the array every time you add a new entry* the backed array will try to resize every time it lacks the space to add a new entry.

Comment: It's not type safe to use arrays of generic types.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza exactly, but I'm not exactly sure how the ArrayList handles the array. Maybe if you remove an element it doesn't resize the array immediately but waits to see if new elements are added.

Comment: @RohitJain yeah true, added this