# how to iterate though Hashtable and return value?

Tags: java, file, dictionary, iterator, hashtable

I have to read a file. File is as below -

123 http://www.xyz.com

143 http://www.qqq.com

I have written below code wherein I read that file into hashtable.

```
public Hashtable<String, String> readDataFromFile(String fileName) {
            try {
                FileReader fr = new FileReader(fileName);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
                String strLine = null;
                String []prop = null;
                while((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    prop = strLine.split("\t");
                    recruiters.put(prop[0], prop[1]);
                }
                br.close();
                fr.close();

            }catch(Exception exception) {
                System.out.println("Unable to read data from recruiter file: " + exception.getMessage());
            }
            return recruiters;
        }
```

This function returns a hashtable with first argument as id and second as the link

Now, I want to write a function in which I can read the hashtable and also append the second argument to first and that function should return a total url as result..

something like www.abc.com/123

This is how I started but its not working for me.. Plesae suggest improvement.

```
public String readFromHashtable(Hashtable recruiters){

            String url=null;        
            Set<String> keys = hm.keySet();
            for(String key: keys){
                //Reading value and key
                // Appending id into url and returning each of the url.
            }
            return url;

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want both values (key + value), it's easiest to iterate over the [entries](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html)
 with [`.entrySet()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html#entrySet%28%29).

You need to somehow collect your URLs. In your current code, you reassign the `url` variable every time the loop repeats, so in the end, you only return the last url.

Something like this should work:

```
public List<String> readFromHashtable(Hashtable recruiters){
    List<String> urls = new ArrayList<String>(recruiters.size());      
    for(Entry e : recruiters.entrySet()){
        urls.add(e.getValue() + '/' + e.getKey());
    }
    return urls;
}
```

Also, why are you using HashTable instead of HashMap? [The main difference is that HashTable is synchronized (used for threaded applications) and HashMap is not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40471/differences-between-hashmap-and-hashtable). If you are not using threads to operate on the HashTable, you might prefer HashMap.