# Is iterator of HashMap fail-safe?

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

I was reading a properties of HashMap. And found [an answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7644118/907687) having lot of votes which says:

> Iterator in the HashMap is fail-safe while the enumerator for the Hashtable is not.

While the JavaDoc says

> The iterators returned by all of this class's "collection view methods" are fail-fast:

Actually the number of votes on that answered has confused me. Else I think it is fail-fast only.

Can someone explain?

Answer (score 2):

Iterator of HashMap is fail-fast It will throw an ConcurrentModificationException if you try to modify while iterating over it, 
while collection which come under "java.util.concurrent" package have  fail-safe iterator. you can modify the collection while iterating over it. Mainly used in Multi threaded environment

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your understanding is correct.

**Fail-fast**: Fail *asap* by making checks aggressively. `HashMap`'s iterator is fail-fast because it throws a `ConcurrentModificationException` as soon as it detects change in underlying structure.

Answer (score 1):

> I think it is fail-fast only.

You are correct.  The person who wrote that Answer probably doesn't understand the difference between fail-fast and fail-safe.

> Actually the number of votes on that answered has confused me.

Lots of votes doesn't necessarily mean that an SO Answer is correct.  I spotted a couple of *other* problems with that Answer as well.  IMO, it does NOT deserve the large number of upvotes that it has received.

Unfortunately, people vote for Answers for a variety of reasons, which can lead to all sorts of anomalies.

Comment: You have not replied on that question. You meant It certainly deserve this many upvotes ?

Comment: How have I not answered the question?

Answer (score 0):

A lot of readers react on what they expect to read and overlook small discrepancies. The answer you linked actually explains the meaning of fail-fast so it’s only a single word that does not match there: “fail-safe” vs. “fail-fast”.

The other point is that a lot of people accept answers sounding plausible. I guess, no one has really tested whether `Hashtable`’s enumerator really behaves differently than `HashMap`’s iterator. Both attempt to fail-fast as of version 1.6.0_35 I just checked.

Answer (score 0):

Well I was confused by this as well, but actually it is very simple:

Say we have:

```
Hashtable<String, Integer> ht = new Hashtable<String, Integer>();
HashMap<String, Integer> hm = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

Then for hm we can do hm.keySet().iterator() which returns an iterator and is fast-fail;
while for ht, we can both do ht.keySet().iterator which returns an iterator and is fast-fail, and do ht.keys() which returns an enumeration object and is NOT fast-fail.