# Why do unsynchronized objects perform better than synchronized ones?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

Question arises after reading [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40471/differences-between-hashmap-and-hashtable). What is the difference between synchronized and unsynchronized objects? Why are unsynchronized objects perform better than synchronized ones?

Comment: only one thread at a time can use the synchronized object, thus the other threads have to wait..

Comment: plus there's a cost associated with the locking mechanism, so even with a single thread it's slower if synchronization is happening.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> What is the difference between Synchronized and Unsynchronized objects ? Why is Unsynchronized Objects perform better than Synchronized ones ?

`HashTable` is considered synchronized because its methods are marked as `synchronized`.  Whenever a thread enters a `synchronized` method or a `synchronized` block it has to first get exclusive control over the monitor associated with the object instance being synchronized on.  If another thread is already in a `synchronized` block on the same object then this will cause the thread to block which is a performance penalty as others have mentioned.

However, the `synchronized` block also does memory synchronization before and after which has memory cache implications and also restricts code reordering/optimization both of which have significant performance implications.  So even if you have a single thread calling entering the `synchronized` block (i.e. no blocking) it will run slower than none.

One of the real performance improvements with threaded programs is realized because of separate CPU high-speed memory caches.  When a threaded program does memory synchronization, the blocks of cached memory that have been updated need to be written to main memory and any updates made to main memory will invalidate local cached memory.  By synchronizing more, again even in a single threaded program, you will see a performance hit.

As an aside, `HashTable` is an older class.  If you want a reentrant `Map` then `ConcurrentHashMap` should be used.

Answer (score 2):

Popular speaking the Synchronized Object is a single thread model，if there are 2 thread want to modify the Synchronized Object . if the first one get the lock of the Object ,that the last one should be waite。but if the Object is Unsynchronized，they can operat the object at the same time，It is the reason that why the Unsynchronized is unsafe。

Comment: Thanks buddy. simple question I've asked.. :(

Comment: FYI: There are other performance implications in `synchronized` blocks.  I've addressed these in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

For synchronization to work, the JVM has to prevent more than one thread entering a synchronized block at a time.  This requires extra processing than if the synchronized block did not exist placing additional load on the JVM and therefore reducing performance.

The exact locking mechanisms in play when synchronization occurs are explain in [How the Java virtual machine performs thread synchronization](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076971/java-concurrency/how-the-java-virtual-machine-performs-thread-synchronization.html)

Answer (score 0):

Synchronization is useful because it allows you to prevent code from being run twice at the same time (commonly called *concurrency*). This is important in a threaded environment for a multitude of reasons. In order to provide this guarantee the JVM has to do extra work which means that performance decreases. Because synchronization requires that only one process be allowed to execute at a time, it can cause multi-threaded programs to function as slowly (or slower!) than single-threaded programs.

It is important to note that the amount of performance decrease is not always obvious. Depending on the circumstances, the decrease may be tiny or huge. This depends on all sorts of things.

Finally, I'd like to add a short warning: Concurrent programming using synchronization is *hard*. I've found that usually other concurrency controls better suit my needs. One of my favorites is [Atomic Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html). This utility is great because it very narrowly limits the amount of synchronized code. This makes it easier to read, maintain and write.

Answer (score 0):

**Synchronization:**

> Array List is non-synchronized which means multiple threads can work
>   on Array List at the same time. For e.g. if one thread is performing
>   an add operation on Array List, there can be an another thread
>   performing remove operation on Array List at the same time in a multi
>   threaded environment
>
> while Vector is synchronized. This means if one thread is working on
>   Vector, no other thread can get a hold of it. Unlike Array List, only
>   one thread can perform an operation on vector at a time.

**Performance:**

> Synchronized operations consumes more time compared to
>   non-synchronized ones so if there is no need for thread safe
>   operation, Array List is a better choice as performance will be
>   improved because of the concurrent processes.