# Save/Load data in java

Tags: java, list

I would like to do some sort of triple array in java to save/load some data, but I want to have some sort of key. Let's say I want a list, that contains the phone numbers of 2 of my friends, William and Mike. So I want to do something like getPhoneNumber("William"); and it will return the number based on the string "William" I gave it. I am not sure how to explain this, I hope someone can guide me.

EDIT: I forgot to mention, I need to save 3 things. So let's say based on the name "William" It should have like, phone number and age or something like that

Comment: I think you should try to explain it more clearly; in this way you will end up with a better analysis of the problem too.

Comment: HashMap.  You can keep your three objects in an array or a custom object, inserted in the map.

Comment: Sorry I messed up a bit the whole thing, I wasn't sure how to explain it. about HashMap, could you give me an example how to store 3 objects? so I want the first to be used as a key, and return the other 2 objects

Comment: Create an object to store the other two.  Put that object into the Map as the "value".

Answer (score 2):

Try using the classes that implement the [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) interface, meaning that they provide the functionalities you are looking for.

[HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) is one of such classes:

```
import java.util.HashMap;

class ContactInformation {
    public String phone;
    public int age;
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<String, ContactInformation> phones = new HashMap<String, ContactInformation>();

        String name = "William";
        ContactInformation ci = new ContactInformation();
        ci.phone = "...";
        ci.age = 21;

        phones.put(name, ci);
        System.out.println(phones.get(name).phone);
        System.out.println(phones.get(name).age);
    }
}
```

You might also run into [Hashtable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html), but I think that's overkill for what you want. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40471/differences-between-hashmap-and-hashtable) for an explanation of the difference between `HashMap` and `Hashtable`.

Comment: Please provide an example of usage, to make a decent answer.

Comment: Thanks but I forgot to mention, I need 3 columns, so Map will not work since it supports 2. Is there something similar that accepts 3?

Comment: You can create a class with all the attributes you need. For instance, a `ContactInformation` class with `phone` and `email` attributes, and then have your `HashMap` be like `<String, ContactInformation>`.

Comment: @Allan I second that; if you need to store more info regarding the same 'reference' (the person name here), it's best to write a separate object that will store all the information and then use a Map like here suggested. So that if in the future another info should be added to the person, you will only change the object properties, but not the map.

Comment: Thanks, I created it a bit differently but I still used hashmap and class similar to your example. Thanks a lot!