# Setting up an array of hashtables in Java

Tags: java, hashtable

Can someone tell me how to properly define an array of hashtables in java? The purpose that I need this for is I have 6 nodes, and each node can have a number of links where a link consists of a linkid(int) and value(int). If anyone has any suggestions, I would appreciate it. Each node can have multiple links.

I have been using an arraylist of hashtables before but when compiled it, a warning appears that my java file uses unchecked or unsafe operations, to recompile with -Xlint. When I recompiled the program, it appears that Java does not like an arraylist of hashtables...

My code was like this:

```
ArrayList<Hashtable<Integer,Integer>> DB_entry;
DB_entry = new ArrayList<Hashtable<Integer,Integer>>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        Hashtable temp = new Hashtable();
        DB_entry.add(temp);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
List<Map<Integer,Integer>> DB_entry = new ArrayList<Map<Integer, Integer>>();
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> row = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    // Populate the map here.
    DB_entry.add(row);
}
```

`Hashtable` is a JDK 1.0 data structure; `HashMap` is preferred.

What is 6?  Magic numbers like this are a very bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

You define `DB_entry` as `ArrayList<Hashtable<Integer,Integer>>` but you are trying to add `Hashtable` elements to it, which is the same as adding `Hashtable<Object,Object>` elements to it. Define your `Hashtable`s as `Hashtable<Integer, Integer> temp = new Hashtable<Integer, Integer>();` in your loop! Or `Hashtable<Integer, Integer> temp = new Hashtable<>();` If you are using java 7+

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that

```
Hashtable temp = new Hashtable();
```

is not the same generic definition as `Hashtable<Integer,Integer>`.  If you replace it with

```
Hashtable<Integer,Integer> temp = new Hashtable<>();
```

that issue should go away.  Also, consider using `HashMap` instead.  See [Differences between HashMap and Hashtable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40471/differences-between-hashmap-and-hashtable)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you don't use a old  JDK, i recommend to use diamond constructor

Second suggestion is that your `DB_entry`, should be a type of `List`, not `ArrayList`.

Third, as someone mentioned before, you should use `HashMap`, as it is much better.

Unless you dont do something with new maps in that loop, then is no need to create it as a local variable.

Your code should look like:

```
List<Map<Integer, Integer>> DB_entry;
        DB_entry = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            DB_entry.add(new HashMap<>());
        }
```

doing so, code is much easier to read.