# Java Equivalent for where in C#

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

What is Java 8 equivalent method for `where` extension method in C#?

How can I filter element of a `Hashtable` in Java 8 using lambda expression

Comment: don't you just want `mytable.stream().filter(e -> ...)` ?

Comment: Yet another tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/reduction.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually he's asking about hashtable, but there is not much a difference there.

```
        Hashtable<String, Integer> someHashTable;
        someHashTable.entrySet().stream().filter((entry)-> entry.getValue()>3).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Here's the tutorial I've used to understand java8 new features including streams http://winterbe.com/posts/2014/03/16/java-8-tutorial/ best one I've found so far. Enjoy :)

Comment: also as Brian said below, Hashtable is a history use HashMap instead :)

Answer (score 11):

You need to use the stream [filter()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-) function, which takes a [Predicate](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html) object defining your filtering criteria.

Here's a [useful tutorial](http://www.dreamsyssoft.com/java-8-lambda-tutorial/filter-tutorial.php). Note the usage:

```
List<User> olderUsers = users. 
                        stream().
                        filter(u -> u.age > 30).
                        collect(Collectors.toList());
```

and the subsequent collection into a collection type of your choice.

Note that I'd likely avoid `Hashtable` in preference to `HashMap`. See [this useful SO entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40471/differences-between-hashmap-and-hashtable).