# Is the HashTable obsolete in Java?

Tags: java, hashtable

I found these description in JDK 1.7's HashTable comment.

> If a thread-safe implementation is not needed, it is recommended to use
>        {@link HashMap} in place of {@code Hashtable}.  If a thread-safe
>        highly-concurrent implementation is desired, then it is recommended
>        to use {@link java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap} in place of
>        {@code Hashtable}.

Then I think it have no situations to use HashTable.

Comment: Yes, it is fair to say that

Comment: Correct, it's obsolete but you'll see it's used in places (eg a parent of java.util.Properties). Similarly `java.util.Vector` has been replaced by `java.util.ArrayList` and `Collections.synchronizedList(List)`

Comment: What part of your question isn't answered by the text you quoted?

Comment: @EJP the text doesn't cover the case where thread safety is required but high concurrency is not expected.

Comment: @EJP When thread safety is required but high concurrency is not expected, is HashTable more efficient than ConcurrentHashMap?

Comment: @xinzhao probably it is, very slightly; however, if you were concerned about performance, it would probably be better to re-work your design so that you didn't require thread-safety from the hashtable and then use `HashMap` instead. My comment above is not intended to imply that `Hashtable` is not obsolete, I was merely pointing out that the text you quote does _not_ in fact completely answer your question.

Comment: @davmac I see, thank you very much.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Differences between HashMap and Hashtable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40471/differences-between-hashmap-and-hashtable)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's been more or less obsolete since java 1.2. You should use `HashMap` or `ConcurrentHashMap`.

Comment: In most cases that's true. In the other cases, use `ConcurrentHashMap`