# How to create a Hashtable using a method as a struct

Tags: java, hashtable

My overall goal is to fill a `Hashtable` with employee data and be able to access/modify that data then print it out.
Given my `Employee` class here, can I use it like a struct in C? I'm trying to figure out how to initialize a `Hashtable` and fill it with this data but I'm sort of confused on how to implement it.

```
public class Employee {

    private String empName;
    private int empNum;
    private String empJob;

    public Employee(String empName, int empNum, String empJob)
    {
        this.empName = empName;
        this.empNum = empNum;
        this.empJob = empJob;

    }

    public int getEmpName()
    {
        return empName;
    }
    public String getEmpNum()
    {
        return empNum;
    }
    public String getEmpJob()
    {
        return empJob;
    }    
}
```

So, I tried this in main, using String as the key, so I want to use the names as the key so you can search by name. I'm also trying to manually fill it so I can test everything. Also, am I able to access say, the employee number on it's own? if so, how can I do this?

```
    public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Hashtable<String,Employee> EmployeeTable = new Hashtable<String,Employee>(); 
        Employee Object = new Employee("Donald","Donald", 3, "Engineer");
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance everyone!

Comment: Also, what exactly is your problem? You created a class, then created an instance in your main and then? What have you tried to do with it, where are your problems, what happened, ....?

Comment: What do you mean by: `"access the employee number on its own"`? Something like `employeeTable.get("Donald").getEmpNum()`?

Comment: You should fix your Employee class first and make sure it compiles before anything else.

Comment: Fixed the Employee class on here, I apologize about the typo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to achieve is rather this:

```
// Create my Hashtable using the diamond notation indicating  to use the type arguments
// corresponding to the context which is <String, Employee> here
Map<String, Employee> EmployeeTable = new Hashtable<>();
Employee employee = new Employee("Donald", 3, "Engineer");
// put my employee into my map using empoyee's name as key
EmployeeTable.put(employee.getEmpName(), employee);
```

What you are looking for is [Map#put(key, value)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#put-K-V-)

After fixing several typo issues, your class Employee should be:

```
public class Employee {

    ...
    public Employee(String empName, int empNum, String empJob)
    {
        ...
    }

    public String getEmpName()
    {
        return empName;
    }
    public int getEmpNum()
    {
        return empNum;
    }
    ...
}
```

**NB:** `Hashtable` is an outdated class, you should not use it anymore, if you don't intend to share it use an [`HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) instead and if you want to share it use a [`ConcurrentHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-)

Answer (score 2):

You can add elements to your Hashtable using the `put` method. You just need to specify the **key** and the **value**.

Then you can retrieve values using the `get` method and specifying the key.

## Example Usage:

```
Hashtable<String, Employee> table = new Hashtable<String, Employee>();
Employee bob = new Employee(...);
table.put("Bob", bob);
```

Then later you can say...

```
table.get("Bob");
```

and this will return Bob's Employee object for you.

## Problems with your code:

There are a few problems with your code that you should be aware of.

#### 1. Your Employee Constructor is wrong.

You've got a constructor for `Product` inside of your Employee class. This is illegal syntax and will not compile (I hope). Instead, you should use the `Employee` constructor.

#### 2. Your Hashtable variable name matches the Object class.

You've named a variable `Object`. [Object](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) is the class that all java classes inherit from, so you *really* shouldn't name something this (if it even lets you at all).

The [Object documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) mentions this...

> Class Object is the root of the class hierarchy. Every class has Object as a superclass. All objects, including arrays, implement the methods of this class.

#### 3. Incorrect Hashtable types.

You've put the wrong types in your Hashtable declaration.

You wrote...

```
Hashtable<String, Employee> EmployeeTable = new Hashtable<String, Product>();
```

When really it should be...

```
Hashtable<String, Employee> employeeTable = new Hashtable<String, Employee>();
```

*(Product changed to Employee)*
*(I also changed the variable to be lowercase)*

## Notes:

- All of the documentation for Hashtable can be found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html#put(K,%20V)).
- You may also be interested in using a [HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) instead of a Hashtable. They're almost identical but HashMap isn't threadsafe. You can see some of the differences [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40471/differences-between-hashmap-and-hashtable). If you *really* need a threadsafe map then I'd recommend [ConcurrentHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html), it's up to you to decide which one suits you the best though.
- It's Java convention for variable names to start with lowercase letters. You don't *have* to follow this but it's definitely a good idea to. Syntax highlighters will no longer argue with you if you do.

Comment: A lot of work, for such a low-quality question. But, well done! Hope you get some more upvotes for this piece of work.

Comment: @GhostCat Thanks for the nice comment, I enjoy seeing positivity on this website. Anything to help out and boost the reputation a little bit haha.

Comment: Yeah, and the really bad thing: that guy got -5 on his questions; so worst case; he will delete his question at some point. Puff goes your answer (and mine). Thus, be careful when putting so much effort on answering low quality stuff like this. I am not implying that you better upvote him to protect your work; of course not ;-)

Comment: Don't upvote me, and no I wont be deleting this. All of these answers were great and I whole-hardheartedly appreciate them. I am very new to stackoverflow and getting the hang of Java again. This is a learning process for me. I'll do my best to ask better questions in the future. On a positive note, everyone truly helped out so much and in a digestible way.

Answer (score 1):

There are various things **wrong** with your class.

Example: the class is called **Employee**. Then the constructor must use that name, and nothing else!

So, it shouldn't read

```
public Product(String empName, int empNum, String empJob)
```

but

```
public Employee(String empName, int empNum, String empJob)
```

And then your call

```
Hashtable<String,Employee> EmployeeTable = new Hashtable<String,Product>();
```

could be correctly written down as

```
Hashtable<String,Employee> table = new Hashtable<>();
```

And no, a **Hashtable** is not a struct. A hashtable is a **collection** class; in other words: it is a Map. It **maps** a key (String in your case) to Employee objects.

But, well, stackoverflow is not a service where other people debug and explain your code to you. So, take my input as starting point; and for example: start reading the compiler messages.

Comment: "new Hashtable>();" <- You missed a "<"