# optimize a java code that match 2 text files having enormous size

Tags: java, file, match

i have a file containing the index of the document and publication date:

0, 2012-05-26T00:00:00Z

1, 2012-05-26T00:00:00Z

5, 2010-06-26T00:00:00Z

10, 2014-05-26T00:00:00Z

and a second text file containing the term frequency and the index of the doc that belongs to him:

was, 15, 1

kill, 10,1

tunisia, 5, 5

peace, 1, 0

i have this method that match both of the files so i can get a third file with this form:

was, 15, 2012-05-26T00:00:00Z

kill, 10,2012-05-26T00:00:00Z

tunisia, 5, 2010-06-26T00:00:00Z

peace, 1, 2012-05-26T00:00:00Z

I tested the method of a test file and it work fine but my file's size is 1T so my program has been in execution for 4 days and still working. would you plz help me to optimize it or give me another method.

```
 public void matchingDateTerme (String pathToDateFich, String pathTotermeFich)  {

  try {

        BufferedReader inTerme = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(pathTotermeFich));
        BufferedReader inDate = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(pathToDateFich));
        String lineTerme,lineDate;
        String idFich, idFichDate,dateterm,key;
        Hashtable<String, String> table = new Hashtable<String, String>();
        String[] tokens,dates;
        Enumeration ID=null;
        File tempFile = new File(pathTotermeFich.replace("fichierTermes", "fichierTermes_final"));
        FileWriter fileWriter =new FileWriter(tempFile);
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);

        //read file date
        while ((lineDate = inDate.readLine()) != null) {
            dates = lineDate.split(", ");
            idFichDate = dates[0].toLowerCase();
            dateterm=dates[1];
            table.put(idFichDate, dateterm);
        }

        while ((lineTerme = inTerme.readLine()) != null) {
            tokens = lineTerme.split(", ");
            idFich = tokens[2].toLowerCase();
            String terme=tokens[0];
            String freq=tokens[1];
            //lire hachtable
            ID = table.keys();
            while(ID.hasMoreElements()) {
               key = (String) ID.nextElement();
               if(key.equalsIgnoreCase(idFich)){
                   String line=terme+", "+freq+", "+table.get(key);
                   System.out.println("Line: "+line);
                   writer.write(line);
                   writer.newLine();
               }
            }
        }


        writer.close();
        inTerme.close();
        inDate.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



}
```

Comment: you should https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide_and_conquer_algorithms split your input files with one file per index modulo, merge files for same modulo, build the file that aggregate merged files. You can then find the fastest diviser (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) IT WILL LOT FASTER since you compute rows only for matching modulo

Comment: you should be able to run it in less than one day with a standard hard drive

Comment: another approach could be to generate fixed line length files and perform a soart of the lines using memory map file, then run your algo with the sorted files. I think the divide and conquer is faster

Comment: would you please explain briefly your method i didn't get it. thx

Comment: see my answer bellow

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the `Hashtable` for what it is : *An object that maps keys to values*

Iterating over keys is useless and expensive, just use the `get` method :

```
if (table.get(idFich) != null) {
    String line = terme + ", " + freq + ", " + table.get(key);
    System.out.println("Line: " + line);
    writer.write(line);
    writer.newLine();
}
```

As VGR said in comment, using a `HashMap` which is not synchronized, will be faster. More information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40471/differences-between-hashmap-and-hashtable)

Comment: This is true, but it’s not enough.  The code is doing a case-insensitive match.  So the Hashtable needs to be built with keys that have been lowercased, and the key passed to `get` also needs to be lowercased.  Also, a non-synchronized Map like HashMap will be faster.

Comment: so if i change this part it will save much time ?

Comment: @VGR : already done. Insertion : `idFichDate = dates[0].toLowerCase();` Reading : `idFich = tokens[2].toLowerCase();` I agree for the HashMap part.

Comment: @Imen Majdoubi : yes, a lot but still it will take time.

Comment: i will change the HashMap part :) but can i run two execution at the same time on eclipse? because i don't want to cut down the execution and start it again with the modified code ?

Comment: With the same set of files ? No. Kill the other execution.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of considerations.

1. Does this absolutely have to be done in java? 
   If yes, can you sort the files before you start reading them?
2. Do you have to run through the files in a single pass (highly doubt).
   If not, you should split the sorted files into parts, and only run through a subset of entries in the part-file.
3. Are both the files in excess of 1T?
   If not, you should start with the file with lesser size.

Given
file1:

```
0,2012-05-26T00:00:00Z
1,2012-05-26T00:00:00Z
5,2010-06-26T00:00:00Z
10,2014-05-26T00:00:00Z
```

and file2:

```
was,15,1
kill,10,1
tunisia,5,5
peace,1,0
```

Here is an awk-based solution based on updated inputs:

```
awk -F',' 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2;next}{if(a[$3]==""){a[$3]=0}; print $1,",",$2,",",a[$3]} ' file1 file2
```

Output:

```
was , 15 , 2012-05-26T00:00:00Z
kill , 10 , 2012-05-26T00:00:00Z
tunisia , 5 , 2010-06-26T00:00:00Z
peace , 1 , 2012-05-26T00:00:00Z
```

[This answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/707843/merge-files-using-a-common-column) was helpful for me to derive above solution.

Comment: the file is sorted i just gave u an example but my file is sorted alphabetically.

Comment: even if i split it i will have to execute it on all parts than merge all of them so where is the point? and i started with the file with lesser size //read file date

Comment: and if u have another solution even if not in java but will save me much time i will be thankful

Comment: this will not solve the overall complexity of O(n*n)... large files will still be prossessed for days...

Comment: @Mahesh my input file is not the same with the one u put it. i have a space before the last column ( was, 15, 1) so your script is not working.would you plz give me a solution

Answer (score 0):

You should use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide_and_conquer_algorithms approach with the following pseudo algo :

```
If A and B are your two large files
Open file A(1..n) for writing
Open file A for reading
  for line in file A
    let modulo = key % n
    write line in file A(modulo)
Open file B(1..n) for writing
Open file B for reading
  for line in file B
    let modulo = key % n
    write line in file B(modulo+1)
for i = 1..n
  Open file R(i) for writing
  Open files A(i) and B(i)
    merge those files into R(i) using key matching as you do
Open file R for writing
for i = 1..n
  append R(i) to R
```

try using n = 1024 if your key are uniform it will end up matching files of 1GB

you need free space on your disk (three time the size of A+B if you do not clean the files)

Comment: @Mahesh thank u for ur help would this work on windows 10 ? if i install the Linux Bash Shell ?