# How to create a dictionary in java, similar to the ones in python?

Tags: java, python

I am working on a text based game in java and would like to use a python like dictionary for the map, the HashMap doesn't really work for me since i want to have multiple values linked to the one dictionary e.g.

In python you can define a dictionary like this:

```
room_x = { "name": "X",

"description":"Random description",

"exits": {linked to another dictionary},

"items": list_of_players_items}
```

Is something similar possible in Java?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any reason you don't create a class with fields, like a good little Object-Oriented programmer using an Object-Oriented language?

Comment: Please try a few Google searches before asking a new question, especially for common tasks.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 just FYI I wasn't specifically asking for a HashMap solution, but asking how to replicate the dictionary function from python in java(Hoping for a better solution than HashMap). The fact that  HashMap solution turned out to be the best way to do it, doesn't make it the same question as the one you tagged.

Comment: This question isn't the same as the linked one - it just contains duplicate information. If, during your research, you had come across that page, it would have fully resolved the issue. That's what duplicates mean. :)

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 based on what you said, nobody should ask a question here, they can always find answers related to their specific problems:)

Comment: @HaifengZhang - Not _nobody_ - it's very desirable for people facing new problems that they cannot resolve with thorough research to ask new questions. But yes, if five seconds of Googling would have answered a question, ___of course___ a new question isn't needed. :)

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 please stop down-voting my other answers on this site.

Comment: @HaifengZhang - I vote a lot around here, to provide input on whether I think a question or answer is useful (just like everyone else does). I cannot say whether I have voted on any of your posts (as voting is anonymous), but I can say that I am unable to give anyone special treatment as you request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`HashMap` can do the work:

```
HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();  //<key,value>  both key and value are Strings
hashMap.put("name", "X");
hashMap.put("description", "Random description");
```

To link multiple values. you need to change the key value pair types as

```
HashMap<String,HashMap<String, String>> linkedMap = new HashMap<>();  // key is string and value is HashMap<String, String>
HashMap<String,String> itemsMap = new HashMap<>();
itemsMap.put("item1", "this is first item");
itemsMap.put("item2", "this is second item");
linkedMap.put("items", itemsMap);
```

Above code is just a quick example I wrote, you need to declare the real type of your data, it doesn't have to be `String`.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

`HashMap` or `Hashtable` is enough. Both have key-value pairs, where key is a String and value can be any object. So you can define it like `HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>()`.

The value can be anything (even null for HashMap not Hashtable).

So you can have another `HashMap` as the value, which solves **"exits": {linked to another dictionary}**

And a `List` as the value, which solves **"items": list_of_players_items**

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40471/differences-between-hashmap-and-hashtable) gives difference between HashMap and Hashtable.

Sample code :

```
List players = // some List
HashMap exits = // some Map
HashMap<String, Object> room_x = new HashMap<String, Object>();
map.put("name",name_string);
map.put("desc",desc_string);
mp.put("exits",exits);
map.put("items",players);
```