# In java Hashtable uses which resolution technique internally?

Tags: java, hashtable

After reading posts , I am confused in java Hashtable internally uses separate chaining or Linked List or open close addressing for handling hashtable collisions.

Can someone tell me hashtable uses which techquie internally?

Comment: You can always look at the source code; [here's one copy I found with a quick search](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/Hashtable.java.html) (it's JDK 7, though). There's a `src.jar` or `src.zip` in the JDK's `lib` directory (only OpenJDK for v11+).

Comment: Why don't you just look for yourself in the sourcecode?

Comment: Generally speaking Hashtable is a legacy API replaced by HashMap in Java 1.2.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder thank you ,  I found a single bucket stores multiple entries, which must be searched sequentially. Does it mean It uses Linked List ? M I correct?

Comment: @kavya - Buckets where each bucket is a singly-linked list, yes.

Comment: Also note https://stackoverflow.com/q/40471/10452693

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the source (there are some online sources, or there's a `src.jar` or `src.zip` in the `lib` directory of the JDK—I think with JDK 11+ it's only in the OpenJDK, not Oracle's), you can see that `Hashtable` is implemented as an array of buckets, and each bucket is a singly-linked list.

The data is stored here:

```
/**
 * The hash table data.
 */
private transient Entry<?,?>[] table;
```

Then if we look at `get`:

```
public synchronized V get(Object key) {
    Entry<?,?> tab[] = table;
    int hash = key.hashCode();
    int index = (hash & 0x7FFFFFFF) % tab.length;
    for (Entry<?,?> e = tab[index] ; e != null ; e = e.next) {
        if ((e.hash == hash) && e.key.equals(key)) {
            return (V)e.value;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

We can see that the [`hashCode`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()) of the key is used to select the bucket, and then it's a linear search within that bucket for the entry.

---

Note that `Hashtable` is largely a legacy class, superceded by `HashMap` as of Java 1.2. OpenJDK's `HashMap` starts out working largely the way `Hashtable` does, but if the buckets get too large, it switches to using buckets containing `TreeMap`-like structures instead (they're faster to look things up in when the bucket is overfilled).